# Summation formula name

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, reference-request, terminology

What is the name of the following summation formula?

$$\sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)) = \int_1^{n + 1} f - \frac{f(n + 1) + f(0)}2 + \int_1^{n + 1} f'w,$$ where $w$ is the “sawtooth” function, defined by $w(x) = (x – (k + 1/2))$, for $k < x <= k + 1$, if $k$ is an integer.

From this formula one can obtain the sum of the first $n$ $k$-th powers. No guessing is necessary, you just turn the crank. However, you have to start at 1 and work your way up. So, if you want the formula for the sum of the first $n$ cubes, say, then you first use this formula to find the formula for the sum of the first $n$ 1-st powers, and then use all this information to find the formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares, and then, finally, use all this information to find the formula for the sum of the first $n$ cubes.

I’ve been calling it Gauss’s Summation Formula, but attributions are often variable, and there might be a more appropriate one that I should be using. I got taken to the woodshed over this. Here is the woodshed link:

[Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-k-1n-k2-fracnn12n16/48098#48098)

Comment: Isn't this Euler-Maclaurin summation, q.v.?

Comment: @Mike: I tried to edit your question to LaTeX syntax, but I wasn't sure what you meant by "integral(from 1 to n + 1, of f’w)".

Comment: I guess Gerry is right and you meant f'(t)w(t). See the form of Euler summation formulat in thees books: http://books.google.com/books?id=WZX4GEpxPRgC&pg=PA424&dq=%22Euler+summation+formula%22+sawtooth&hl=en&ei=x_IPTu2FMceD-wbXhP3ZDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Euler%20summation%20formula%22%20sawtooth&f=false http://books.google.com/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA54&dq=%22Euler+summation+formula%22&hl=en&ei=gfIPTsTNNcOG-wbopbHHDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22Euler%20summation%20formula%22&f=false

Comment: If, to find $S_{p} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$, it requires that we know $S_{1}, \ldots,  S_{p-1} $, then it isn't that effective, surely? I can think of an extremely simple way to do that -- or, at least, when p is odd!

Comment: May be it's this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula

Comment: @Chandru, Abel's formula is a bit different. One can deduce Euler's from Abel's, as Apostol does on page 78 of Introduction to Analytic Number Theory.

Comment: Could someone please edit the formula for me so that the integrand of the first integral on the RHS is simply “f”? (I am an advocate of dropping the extra baggage.) – and edit the formula so that the integrand of the second integral is “f’w”? Thanks. (I’m struggling with a Chinese operating system, and a lack of knowledge of whatever markup system the rest of you are using for writing mathematical formulas.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the formula should read $$\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)=\int_0^nf(t)\,dt+{f(0)+f(n)\over2}+\int_0^nf'(t)w(t)\,dt$$ where $w(t)=t-[t]-1/2$. This is how it's given as (1) at the Wikipedia article on the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Maclaurin_summation) (it's not Euler-Maclaurin, but is a step along the way to the proof of Euler-Maclaurin). This differs from the way Mike has written it in the handling of $n$ and $n+1$ as upper limits, and 0 and 1 as lower limits, but surely those differences are easy to take into account.

I concur with Martin Sleziak that it's called Euler summation (and not Euler-Maclaurin, despite my earlier comment).

Comment: I would say it's the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula with a first-order remainder term - although it is also a step on the way to proving the infinite series version of the formula.  (An analogy is Taylor's formula: You can express it with a remainder term or as an infinite series.)  And I've seen it called both "Euler's summation formula" and "Euler-Maclaurin summation formula."  In fact, once I called it the former in a paper and was told by a referee to change it to the latter.

Comment: @Mike, so I was right the first time? I can live with that....

Comment: (Essentially it's Euler-Maclaurin indeed but) I've also heard name “Sonin(e) formula” for this particular variant.

Comment: @Grigory, I have found formulas attributed to Sonin but they don't look like the one we're discussing. Do you have a reference?