# Critique on a proof by induction that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2= n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, induction, proof-verification

I need to make the proof for this

1:$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + n^2=\frac{(n(n+1)(2n+1))}{6}$$

By mathematical induction I know that,

If *P(n)* is true for $n>3^2$ then P(k) is also true for *k=N* and also *P(k+1)* must be true.

Then,

2:$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... + k^2=\frac{(k(k+1)(2k+1))}{6}$$

Substitution:

3:$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... +n^2+ (n+1)^2=\frac{((n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1))}{6}$$

**Questions**

**a: Do anyone see notation errors in this post?**

**b:  It is right so far?**

Comment: I don't fully understand what you did with the $k$'s, but in the last part it seems like you assumed what was to be shown instead of relying on induction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461329/mathematical-induction-supported-by-geometric-interpretation

Comment: Perhaps we should go over the induction schema (we'll avoid ZF terminology): if a property (say equation of formulas) holds for some positive integer $n$, and it can be shown that whenever it holds for a positive integer $k$ it then must also hold for $k+1$, then the property holds for all positive integers greater than $n$.

Answer (score 2):

For the third step, notice that
$$ 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + ... +n^2+ (n+1)^2 = \frac{(n(n+1)(2n+1))}{6}+(n+1)^2 $$

$$ =  \frac{(n(n+1)(2n+1))}{6}+\frac{6(n+1)^2}{6}$$

$$ = \frac{(n+1)(n(2n+1)+6(n+1))}{6}=\dots $$

Can you finish it?