# How to solve this limit, hint only

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{9n^2-1^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{9n^2-2^2}}+ \dots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{9n^2-n^2}}\bigg)$$ I need a hint. I see that maybe compute with integral. But what the integrable function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint** Since you ask for a simple hint then: Use a Riemann sum and compute this integral
$$\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{9-x^2}}$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\text{As }\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

Here the $r$( where $1\le r\le n$)th term $=\displaystyle\frac n{\sqrt{9n^2-r^2}}=\frac1{\sqrt{9-\left(\frac rn\right)^2}}$

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589653/evaluate-int-1-0-x2-dx-without-using-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculu

Comment: and where i can see more about $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n\sum_{r=1}^n f\left(\frac rn\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx?$$

Comment: @slmkarta, If you mean examples, you have ample instances here

Comment: I mean the rules

Comment: @slmkarta, Put $b=1,a=0$  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Methods

Answer (score 3):

Well, here is a hint, factor out $n$, and use it to convert it into Riemann Integration.