# How to substitute sum variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am not entirely sure how to use variable substitution for a sum. Take the following example: I would like to compute $$\sum_{i=1}^N(2i-1)^2$$ One straightforward way is to split the sum, i.e. $$4\sum i^2-4\sum i+N=\frac{1}{3}N(4N^2-1)$$ Now I am trying to use variable substitution. Let $j=2i-1\Rightarrow i=\frac{j+1}{2}$. The new limits become:
$$\frac{j+1}{2}=1\Rightarrow j=1\\\frac{j+1}{2}=N\Rightarrow j=2N-1$$. The sum becomes
$$\sum_{j=1}^{2N-1}j^2=\frac{1}{3}n(2n-1)(4n-1)$$
which is wrong :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing lab's answer:  You could write, say
$$
\sum_{j=1,\; j\;\mathrm{odd}}^{2N-1} j^2
$$
but of course the formulas you know for the case without the "odd" clause would not apply to it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $j$ does not vary from $1$ to $2N-1$ with increment $=1$ but with increment $=2$

so, we can not apply [Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16)

Comment: @Downvoter, I beg you to pinpoint the mistake. Have you noticed the reference of this answer in the other answer?