# Proof of $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=n^3/3+n^2/2+n/6$

Tags: proof-verification

I'm having a difficulty understanding this 
[image]

It's only the addition part which I'm not following.

From what I've understood:

If we have a certain number of formulas and we add them, this is what happens on the left side:

$$3\cdot 1^2+3\cdot 2^2+\cdots+3\cdot (n-1)^2=3\cdot(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2)$$

$$3\cdot 1+3\cdot 2+\cdots +3\cdot (n-1)=3\cdot (1+2+\cdots+(n-1))$$

and we know that when we have a sequence of formulas, it will be $(n-1)$ formulas, so we represent the total numbers of $1$'s in the form $(n-1)$

Finally,

$$3(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2)+3(1+2+\cdots+(n-1))+(n-1)=\cdots$$

Now, for the right hand side, if we have, as an example:

$$2^3-1^3$$

$$3^3-2^3$$

$$4^4-3^3$$

$$n^3-4^3$$

We can reorganize this:

$$2^3-1^3$$

$$-2^3+3^3$$

$$4^4-3^3$$

$$n^3-4^3$$

We cancel which leaves us with

$$0-1^3$$

$$4^4+0$$

$$n^3-4^3$$

Rearrange and cancel:

$$0-1^3$$

$$0+4^4$$

$$n^3-4^3$$

Which leaves us with

$$n^3-1^3$$

Finally
$$3\cdot(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2)+3\cdot(1+2+\cdots+(n-1))+(n-1)=n^3-1^3$$
The author doesn't say how exactly he did it, but would this way be the correct one? Or it's not the correct way?

Thank you!

Comment: Your analysis is correct. I am a little surprised that the author did not take $k=1$ to $n$.

Comment: Ok thank you for your response.

Comment: @Astroman Is it better now?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the proof is to use that $$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1+1}_n=n$$ $$1+2+\cdots+k=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$ and telescopy. We write $(k+1)^3-k^3=3k^2+3k+1$ using the binomial theorem. We can do this for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. This gives 
$$\begin{align}
(1+1)^3-1^3&=3\cdot \color{red}{1^2}+3\cdot \color{green}{1}+\color{blue}{1}\\
(2+1)^3-2^3&=3\cdot \color{red}{2^2}+3\cdot \color{green}{2}+\color{blue}{1}\\
\vdots\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;&=\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\vdots\\
(n+1)^3-n^3&=3\cdot \color{red}{n^2}+3\cdot \color{green}{n}+\color{blue}{1}
\end{align}$$
  Summing all this gives that $$(n+1)^3-1^3=3\color{red}{(1^2+2^2+\cdots +n^2)}+3\color{green}{(1+2+\cdots+n)}+\color{blue}{(1+1+\cdots+1+1)}$$

because on the left side, $(1+1)^3$ cancels with $-2^3$, $(2+1)^3$ cancels with $-3^3$, and so on.

Comment: I don'T know calculus yet... he does it without calculus. Another way of explaining it ?? Thank you !

Comment: @Astroman What do you mean by "calculus"? If you're not comfortable with $\Sigma$ notation, one can write the above replacing $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$ with $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2$ and so on.

Comment: Well, I meant that I have no idea what this greek symbol means, yet.

Comment: Right, I suspected so. Let me fix that.

Comment: @Astroman: For what it's worth, a lot of beautiful mathematics is written using $\sum$ and $\prod$ (the analogous notation for products) and in hindsight I wish I had gotten comfortable with the notations sooner. Now that you know the idea, you might consider rereading Pedro's original post (click the link in the middle of the bottom of the post) to try to familiarize yourself with it :)

Comment: @EricStucky Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

One way to show this is as follows: let's call the sum we seek $S$:
$$
S = 1 + 4 + 9 + \ldots + n^2.
$$
Notice that
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= 1\\
4 &= 1 + 3\\
9 &= 1 + 3 + 5\\
\ldots
\end{align}
$$
In general, we have
$$
n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1),
$$
which follows immediately from the fact that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$
Therefore, the total sum is equal to
$$
S = \sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^l(2k-1).
$$
If we change the order of the sums, we find
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=k}^n(2k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\sum_{l=k}^n 1=
\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(n+1-k).
$$
You can also see this from the fact that
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= 1\\
4 &= 1 + 3\\
9 &= 1 + 3 + 5\\
\ldots\\
n^2 &= 1 + 3 + 5 + \ldots + 2n-1\\
\hline\\
S &= 1\cdot n + 3(n-1) + 5(n-2) + \ldots + (2n-1)\cdot 1\\
&= (2\cdot 1-1)(n+1-1) + (2\cdot 2-1)(n+1-2) + \ldots + (2n-1)(n+1-n)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)(n+1-k).
\end{align}
$$
If we work this out, we get
$$
\begin{align}
S &= (n+1)\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1) - 2\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 + \sum_{k=1}^n k\\
 &= (n+1)n^2 - 2S + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
3S = n^3 + \frac{3n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}, 
$$
so that
$$
S = \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

There is another simple way to do this. $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2&=\sum_{k=1}^nk(k-1)+k\\&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k+1)k(k-1)-k(k-1)(k-2)}{3}+\sum_{k=1}^nk\\&=\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{3}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\&=\frac{1}{3}n^3+\frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{6}n\end{align}$$