# Discrete Math on Induction proofs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show by induction that the following formulas hold for

$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n i^3
= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}
$$

Not sure how to go about this problem. Can someone help please?  Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16

Comment: If someone can give me a head start, that will be great!

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is your fourth question in a row concerning proofs using induction. Are you reading the answers to your previous questions ? If so, how come you still haven't got the slightest idea on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The base case:
$$\sum_{i=1}^1 i^3 = 1^3 = \frac{1^2 2^2}{4}.$$
Now suppose that the result holds for all $k \leq n$. Then 
\begin{align}
   \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^3
&= \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 + (n+1)^3 \\
&= \frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4} + (n+1)^3 \\
&= (n+1)^2 \left( \frac{n^2 }{4} + (n+1) \right) \\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}(n^2 + 4n + 4) \\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2}{4}(n+2)^2 \\
&= \frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}.
\end{align}

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Comment: I got n²(n+1)² + 4(n+1)^3/4 so far. I would be my next step? Thanks

Comment: I've added one more line to bring you a bit closer to the solution (essentially, I factored $(n+1)^2/4$ out of the two terms in the last sum)

Comment: I'm actually little confused of how to do it this way. using the above I have (n+1)²/4 (n+2)² so far.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to include the full solution :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how would (n+2)² can turn to n² at the end. Are we not suppose to end up with n²(n+1)²/4 instead of (n+1)²(n+2)²/4 ??

Comment: No, because, as you'll notice, I'm summing up to $n+1$. I've assumed that the result holds for $n$, which is the term you reference, and want to prove it for $n+1$. So change your $n$ to $n+1$ and your $n+1$ to $n+2$.