# A function f(n), that for any n gives the sum of 1^2 up to n^2?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

I was solving Project Euler's problem # 6, where one has to find the sum of square  of numbers from 1 to 100. I solved it using code and downloaded the Overview provided, to learn from it but I can't understand how the author has formed the function for finding the sum of square of numbers from 1 to n.

I've attached an image, highlighting the part of the document I don't understand. I know this is something really straightforward but I don't get it.

Please help and thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What are your troubles with it? What is not clear ?

Comment: [This other math.se question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16) does not directly answer your question, but it may help with your understanding.

Comment: This is like polynomial regression (in a sense).

Comment: For any polynomial $p(n)$, of degree $d$, the sum $p(1)+p(2)+...+p(n)$ is always a polynomial of degree $d+1$.  In this case $n^2$ has degree 2, so the sum has degree 3.

Comment: What I don't get is how and why is the author assuming this specific function? How did he reach to the conclusion that f(n) = an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d is the function that'll solve his problem?

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your comment clears a lot of my confusion. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a way to establish Faulhaber's formulas (have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(0)=a(0)^3+b(0)^2+c(0)+d=d$$
$$f(1)=a(1)^3+b(1)^2+c(1)+d=a+b+c+d$$
$$f(2)=a(2)^3+b(2)^2+c(2)+d=8a+4b+2c+d$$
$$f(3)=a(3)^3+b(3)^2+c(3)+d=27a+9b+3c+d$$

Have you understood this much? After this, the numeric values of $f(0)$, $f(1)$, $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ have been found manually.

This gives us 4 equations that can be solved.

Comment: What I don't get is how and why is the author assuming this specific function?

Comment: @misfitmaniac it does not say. You can dream of a function, if you show that it works, then it works. The author essentially said : "I have a strong gut feeling that the answer is a third degree polynomial. Which coefficients though? My gut is not that precise.. Let's assume it is a third degree polynomial; then the coefficients *have* to be such and such. Of course, now I have to show that the formula I found is correct! Doing this by induction is usually the best way. Is it more clear?

Comment: @Ant We have not assumed it is a 3rd degree polynomial, it is a proved fact. It becomes more obvious when you plot it on a graph. Also, you could take a 4 (or even greater, if you want to) degree polynomial of the form $an^4+bn^3+cn^2+dn+e$. This will mean we need to take $f(4)$ also. On solving the system of equations, we get the same result, with $a=0$.

Comment: @user45195 no. *a priori* we do not know if it is a polynomial at all.. It could be anything. We suppose it is, find the correct coefficients, then *show* that it works. It it works, then we proved it. But a priori we assumed it was a polynomial when we had no proof about that

Comment: @Ant I didn't get you. What do you mean by 'we do not know if it is a polynomial at all'? What else could it be?

Comment: @user45195 Well *a priori* pretty much everything! $f(n) = \lfloor{\log n}\rfloor$, or $f(n) = 2^n$. Polynomials are not the only functions that are there! :)

Comment: @Ant Okay, I've asked a question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082357/clarification-on-how-to-prove-polynomial-representations-exist-for-infinite-seri.

Comment: @user45195 very nice and interesting question! One should include such a proof on you statement though, and it would probably be an overkill since the actual proof for $m=2$ is very easy. But I'll look forward for answers on your questions! :-)