# Prove that $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

**Problem:** Prove that $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**My work:** So I think I have to do a proof by induction and I just wanted some help editing my proof.

My attempt:

Let $P(n)=1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. 
Then $$P(1)=1^2=\frac{1(1+1)(2+1)}{6}$$
$$1=\frac{6}{6}.$$
So $P(1)$ is true.

Next suppose that $P(k)=1^2+2^2+\cdots+k^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then adding $(k+1)^2$ to both sides of $P(k)$ we obtain the following:
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots+k^2+(k+1)^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)^2$$
$$=\frac{2k^3+3k^2+k+6(k^2+2k+1)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{2k^3+9k^2+13k+6}{6}$$
$$=\frac{(k^2+3k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)(2(k+1)+1)}{6}$$
$$=P(k+1).$$
Thus $P(k)$ is true for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Hence by mathematical induction, $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Is the question here more so "how to write a nice proof"?

Comment: @crash it is tagged verification. They probably want to know if they are correct.

Comment: @crash basically yea, I want to know what edits I can make to improve it, if im missing anything, etc. I'm new to proof writing

Comment: @dustin It seems a little ambiguous here in my opinion--*prima facie* I don't see any issues; thus, it seems like "editing" in this scenario means more concerning presentation than proof veracity.

Comment: @crash my intention was both presentation and proof veracity editing. I wasn't even sure if my answer was correct

Comment: In terms of small edits: I believe that your $P(k)$ is a proposition, so it might not be best to follow it with an equal sign (maybe you could use a colon instead). I found this read slightly strange when you mentioned adding $(k+1)^2$ "to both sides of $P(k)$."

Comment: Do you like the proof by induction, or by algebra?

Comment: @Garvil What do you mean by algebra? Are you saying there's another way to prove it other than induction, using algebra?

Comment: Oh yes, would you like to know?

Comment: @MathMajor When this formula was derived, it had to be derived without induction.

Comment: @Garvil Yes please!

Comment: @MathMajor I just answered with what I, personally, think is a very good way of giving the solution (my opinion). It is very cleanly laid out. The claims are very clear. All of the steps are also clearly outlined. It could obviously be trimmed considerably, but it is up to the proof writer to omit steps where s/he sees fit.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to provide what I think is a *nice* way of writing up a proof, both in terms of accuracy and in terms of communication. You be the judge(s).

---

**Claim:** For $n\geq 1$, let $S(n)$ be the statement
$$
S(n) : 1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$

**Base step $(n=1)$:** The statement $S(1)$ says $1^2=1(2)(3)/6$ which is true.

**Inductive step $(S(k)\to S(k+1))$:** Fix some $k\geq 1$ and suppose that
$$
S(k) : 1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+k^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}
$$
holds. To be shown is that
$$
S(k+1) : 1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+k^2+(k+1)^2=\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2(k+1)+1)}{6}
$$
follows. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &= 1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+k^2+(k+1)^2\tag{definition}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)^2\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[1em]
  &= (k+1)\left[\frac{k(2k+1)}{6}+(k+1)\right]\\[1em]
  &= (k+1)\frac{k(2k+1)+6(k+1)}{6}\\[1em]
  &= (k+1)\frac{2k^2+k+6k+6}{6}\\[1em]
  &= (k+1)\frac{2k^2+7k+6}{6}\\[1em]
  &= (k+1)\frac{(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2(k+1)+1)}{6}\\[1em]
  &= \text{RHS},
\end{align}
the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$ follows. This completes the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, for every $n\geq 1, S(n)$ is true. $\Box$

Comment: Teach me, oh master, the ways of typing your $L_AT_EX$ so fast

Comment: @AvZ Haha. Lots of patience and practice--I think it mostly comes down to looking at MSWord as the absolutely ridiculously hideous beast that it is. :)

Comment: @MathMajor Glad it helped! I maybe should add, given @AvZ's comment that *part* of the challenge with presenting nice proofs lies in the actual typesetting. You should *definitely* learn $\LaTeX$ and make it your best friend so that writing professional-looking math will be easy. For example, the `align` environment is something very useful for making things clear (helps to add comments on the side sometimes).

Comment: Mathjax's cheats us with `align` though. We can't use `\intertext{}` within the environment which angers me.

Comment: @dustin Yes, there are several things that anger me in terms of what you can do concerning $\LaTeX$ and what you cannot do (on MSE, that is)--I was thinking about posting a Meta question in regards to what is not "implemented" or "imported" in terms of standard $\LaTeX$ distributions. I'm sure this has been asked before though--might you know of a good link that would be informative or is the standard tutorial really all there is?

Comment: It isn't about the site but about [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/#docs)s itself. You have to look at the documentation there to see what has been brought over. However, I think that is a waste. I figure it out as I go. If something doesn't render, it isn't configure in Mathjaxs.

Comment: @dustin Yeah, that sounds annoying. That's what I've been doing too so far. I guess I will continue in that manner (I agree that actually looking through all of the documentation would likely be a waste of time). Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 17):

Consider any natural number $r$. You have $$r^3-(r-1)^3=3r^2-3r+1.$$

Now telescope it: 
$$
1^3-0^3=3-3+1
$$
$$2^3-1^3=3\cdot2^2-3\cdot2+1
$$
$$\vdots
$$
$$
n^3-(n-1)^3=3n^2-3n+1
$$ Now add, and see them cancel out. You are left with $$n^3=3(1^2+2^2+\cdots+ n^2)-3(1+2+3+\cdots+n)+n$$ You must know 
$$
1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.
$$ 
Plug it in, and you get the answer. Also, please see that this method works even for $\sum r^4,r^5,\cdots$. I have tried it out. All you need is the sum of its previous powers.

Comment: You might want to use $\LaTeX$ `\cdot` command for multiplication rather than an odrinary `.` dot: `3\cdot 2^2` produces $3\cdot 2^2$.

Comment: Also, use `\cdots` to get the $\cdots$ where desired.

Comment: Oh, I too thought it looked bad. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it is better now.

Comment: @Garvil For where you just used `\cdots`, it would really be more appropriate to use `\vdots` to get $\vdots$ which is what you are really going for there. Good ole typesetting...takes a while to get used to it. :)

Comment: Now,is it better?

Comment: @Garvil Tell you what--I'll edit your post, and you correct any of my edits you might disagree with.

Comment: OK, I suck at LATEX.

Comment: @Garvil How does that look? All good with you? And you don't suck at $\LaTeX$. Not at all. Some users on here though...phew.

Comment: Could you tell me, what all did you do?

Comment: @Garvil You can see the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1166042/revisions) for any post. Looking at that will show you exactly what all I did.

Comment: @Garvil I just saw the edit history--why did you make a rollback? What you had before was better IMO.

Comment: Yeah sorry for that. I didn't know what a rollback was. So I tried it. Let me roll it back.

Comment: @Garvil Well, at least you got a "Cleanup" badge out of it ;)

Comment: Yeah, that is why I tried it in the first place.

Comment: Is there any record/reference of what year/who thought of this solution first?

Answer (score 0):

Your inductive assumption is such that the formula marked $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ (several lines below) holds for $i=k$:

$$\sum^{i=k}_{i=1} i^2=\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6} $$

You need to prove that for $i=k+1$: $$\sum^{i=k+1}_{i=1} i^2=\color{blue}{\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}}$$

To do this you cannot use: $$\sum^{i=k}_{i=n} i^2=\color{red}{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}} $$ as this *is* what you are trying to prove.

So what you do instead is notice that:
$$\sum^{i=k+1}_{i=1} i^2= \underbrace{\frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}}_{\text{sum of k terms}} + \underbrace{(k+1)^2}_{\text{(k+1)th term}}$$
$$\sum^{i=k+1}_{i=1} i^2= \frac{k(k+1)(2k+1)}{6}+\frac{6(k+1)^2}{6}$$
$$\sum^{i=k+1}_{i=1} i^2= \frac{(k+1)\left(k(2k+1)+6(k+1)\right)}{6}$$
$$\sum^{i=k+1}_{i=1} i^2= \frac{(k+1)(2k^2+\color{green}{7k}+6)}{6}=\frac{(k+1)(2k^2+\color{green}{4k+3k}+6)}{6}=\frac{(k+1)\left(2k(k+2)+3(k+2)\right)}{6}=\color{blue}{\frac{(k+1)(k+2)(2k+3)}{6}}\quad \forall \space k \in \mathbb{N}$$

Which is the relation we set out to prove. So the method is to substitute $i=k+1$ into the formula you are *trying* to prove and then use the inductive assumption to recover the $\color{blue}{\mathrm{blue}}$ equation at the end.