# Proving $2^n > (n+1)^2$ for $n\geq 6$ by induction.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, induction

So here is what I have to prove by induction:

$2^n\gt(n+1)^2$  for $n\ge6$

So, first lets say $n=6$

$$2^6\gt(6+1)^2$$
$$64\ge49$$
Now, assume  $n=k$
$$2^k\gt(k+1)^2\text{  for   } k\ge6$$

Prove $n=k+1$ is true
$$2^{k+1}>(k+2)^2$$
$$2^k *2> k^2+4x+4$$
We can replace $2^k$ with $(k+1)^2$
$$(k+1)^2*2>k^2+4x+4$$
$$k^2+2>4$$
$$k^2>2$$
Now, since $k\ge6$,   $k^2$ must be greater than $2$  $$$$
So, my question is, did I do the proof correctly, or is there a more rigorous method to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, this is how I would structure the meat of your proof:
\begin{align}
2^{k+1} &= 2^k\cdot 2\tag{definition}\\[0.5em]
  &> 2\cdot(k+1)^2\tag{inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
  &= 2(k^2+2k+1)\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
  &= 2k^2+4k+2\tag{expand again}\\[0.5em]
  &> k^2+4k+4\tag{since $k\geq 6$}\\[0.5em]
  &= (k+2)^2.\tag{factor}
\end{align}
That is really all you need to show (of course, in your formal write up, you should include the base case, the inductive assumption, etc.).

Comment: I (sort of) understand your solution (working on deciphering it), but if I was to put my answer on a test, would it be correct?

Comment: @Anonymous Which part do you not understand?

Comment: So, on the left hand side, $2^{k+1}$  would be there throughout the proof?

Comment: @Anonymous If you were to write it all out in one line, it would look like this:
$$
2^{k+1}=2^k\cdot2>2\cdot(k+1)^2=2k^2+4k+2>k^2+4k+4=(k+2)^2.\tag{1}
$$
The idea behind structuring it the way I have is to clearly indicate what is going on at each step. As evident in $(1)$ above, by the chain of relations, you have $2^{k+1} > \cdots > (k+2)^2$, which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: Oh that makes SOO much more sense, thanks!

Comment: Just curious, does my method work? Maybe not for all inequalities, but for some?

Comment: @Anonymous I'm not sure what you meant by "your method." The reason I posted my answer was ultimately to *clean everything up*. Don't take offense at this, but your attempted proof is not very well structured. In fact, you may want to check out an [answer I posted yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1166027/prove-that-1222-cdotsn2-fracnn12n16-for-n-in-mathbbn/1166038#1166038) that shows how one might reasonably structure a very clear proof. You may find it of interest. Part of the struggle is in actually typesetting though. So beef up on $\rm\LaTeX$ and you'll be fine!

Comment: @Anonymous You may also want to check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1139579/why-is-mathematical-induction-a-valid-proof-technique/1139606#1139606) post which explains why induction really works. :)

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Comment: Wait, @crash , couldn't you have just said $(k+1)^2>(k+2)^2$ ?

Comment: @user1843145 When would that inequality you mentioned be true? You can't use that.

Comment: Oh crap, I meant the other way around, but I see that I messed up. But how do you know $2k^2+4k+2>k^2+4k+4$? Is it because you end up with $k^2>2$?

Comment: @user1843145 That's correct. The inequality $k^2>2$ is true for all $k\geq 2$; since you're considering a proposition for all $k\geq6$, then certainly $k^2>2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2 \geq ((n+1)/n)^2$ for your assumption $n \geq 6$.

Comment: Hmm... I don't get it.