# Show, with induction that $1^2 + 2^2 + .... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

Tags: induction

Show, with induction that

$1^2 + 2^2 + .... + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$

My attempt

**Case 1:** n = 1

$LHS = 1^2$

$RHS = \frac{(1+1)(2+1)}{6} = \frac{2*3}{6} = 1$

**Case 2:** n = p

$LHS_{p} = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + p^2$

$RHS_{p} = \frac{p(p+1)(2p+1)}{6}$

**Case 3:** n = p + 1

$LHS_{p+1} = 1^2+2^2+....+p^2+(p+1)^2$

$RHS_{p+1} = \frac{(p+1)((p+1)+1)(2(p+1)+1)}{6}$

Now to show this with induction I think i need to show that

$RHS_{p+1} = RHS_{p} + (p+1)^2$

$RHS_{p+1} = \frac{p(p+1)(2p+1)}{6} + (p+1)^2$

So I need to rewrite

$RHS_{p+1} = \frac{(p+1)((p+1)+1)(2(p+1)+1)}{6} $to be equal to $\frac{p(p+1)(2p+1)}{6} + (p+1)^2$ 
Anyone see how I can do that? Or got any other solution?

Comment: Simplify both expressions (expand, collect, etc.), or equivalently simplify the difference, which should equal $0$. You could also compute the sum using the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: You may find it helpful to read [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1166038/191378) I wrote a good while back concerning this. It would be helpful to write your proof a little more neatly.

Comment: There is also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

In your notation,
$$
\begin{split}
1^2+\ldots+p^2+(p+1)^2
 &= \frac{p(p+1)(2p+1)}{6} + (p+1)^2 \\
 &= \frac{p+1}{6} \left[p(2p+1)+6(p+1)\right] \\
 &= \frac{p+1}{6} \left[2p^2 + 8p+6\right] \\
 &= \frac{(p+1)(p+2)(2p+3)}{6}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Hey thanks man :)