# Time complexity of LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

I am trying to derive the LU decomposition time complexity for an $n \times n$ matrix.

Eliminating the first column will require $n$ additions and $n$ multiplications for $n-1$ rows. Therefore, the number of operations for the first column is $2n(n-1)$. For the second column, we have $n-1$ additions and $n-1$ multiplications, and we do this for $(n-2)$ rows giving us $2(n-1)(n-2)$. Therefore, the total number of operations required for the full decomposition can be written as

$$
\sum_i^n 2(n-i) (n-i+1)
$$

How do we get from this sum to a total cost of $\frac{2}{3}n^3$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy transformation ($j = n-i+1$) easily shows that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n 2(n-i) (n-i+1) &= 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}j(j+1)\\
                            &= 2 \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j^2+j)\\
                            &= 2 \left(\frac{1}{3} n^{3} - \frac{1}{3} n\right)
\end{align}

Then, since we are interested only in the asymptotic behaviour, we drop the $\frac{2}{3}n$ part, and what's left is $\frac{2}{3} n^{3}$.

Comment: I get it up to the $2 \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (j^2 + j)$ .. but then I don't see how did you get the next step. I must be missing something.

Comment: You can use the classical formulas for the sums of the first $n$ squares and the first $n$ integers : $$ \sum_0^n{k^2} =\frac{1}{6} {\left(2 n + 1\right)} {\left(n + 1\right)} n $$ and $$ \sum_0^n{k} =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and adapt them to $n-1$

Comment: I am a little confused. Why don't any of the answers here also consider the part where we have to also find the upper triangular matrix?

Answer (score 4):

Below is the gist. Hope the loose but cleaner notation can help our memory.

$\sum_i^n 2(n-i) (n-i+1)\approx2\sum n^2\approx2\int x^2dx\approx\frac{2}{3}x^3$

$\approx$ is in the sense of top term coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 
$$
2\sum_i^n (n-i)(n-i)+(n-i) = 2\sum_i^n (n-i)^2+2\sum_i^n(n-i)
$$

Now, let's reindex these sums backwards so it's pretty.
$$
2\sum_i^n (i)^2+2\sum_i^n(i)
$$

Now, if you know a little induction (or wolfram alpha) you can prove that
$$ 
\sum_i^n (i)^2 = n^3/3+n^2/2+n/6
$$
and $\sum_i^n i$ is at worst $n^2$. So we have $\frac{2}{3}n^3$

Comment: I don't see how you get that $\sum_i^n (i)^2 = n^2/3 + n^2/2+n/6$

Comment: Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16 is the MSE discussion about it. There are many proofs. One proof is by induction using the formula for $\sum_i^n i$ as a starter. There are some number theoretic proofs. It's a good fact to know.