# Computational costs of different methods of solving systems of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Homework question: given a regular matrix $A\in M^{n\times n}$ and a linear system of equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$, state the preferred method of solving and its computational costs:

1. $A$ has no special properties.
2. $A$ has positive eigenvalues.
3. $A$ is orthogonal.

Solutions that I've been able to find so far:

1. LU-Decomposition, $\approx \frac{2n^3}{3}$. ([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330759/time-complexity-of-lu-decomposition))
2. Cholesky-Decomposition, $\approx \frac{n^3}{3}$. ([Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217738/how-to-calculate-the-cost-of-cholesky-decomposition))
3. Orthogonal Diagonalization, depends on matrix multiplication $\approx n^{2.376}.$ ([Source](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62904/complexity-of-eigenvalue-decomposition))

Are these answers correct, or are there better methods/are the best methods slover?

Comment: Should the linear system be $Ax = b$ rather than $Ax = 0$?

Comment: @littleO yes, thanks

Comment: Here's a hint about the third case: there's a much easier method, which you can discover if you think about the various equivalent definitions of an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @littleO Ah! $A^T = A^{-1}$, and the costs should be therefore $n^2$

Answer (score 2):

General principal is that solving linear equations is no harder than multiplying matrices, regardless of what you know about A (see Burgisser Claussen "Algebraic Complexity Theory" Chapter 15).  So the bound is $O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for an every changing value of $\epsilon$ (by ever changing I mean it changes every few years, we don't know if $\epsilon$ can become arbitrarily small.)  But for example at mimimum using vanilla Strassen you get $O(n^{\log_2 7})$ complexity always.

But to be honest, a lot of that is not quite accurate.  Missing from this is the issue of numerical stability.  If you solve problems over the reals your floating point precision becomes a problem.  So the complexity of "practical" algorithms is highly varied.