# Calculus 2. Calculate $\int_0^3 \left(x^2 +2\right) dx$ by the formal definition.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Calculate by the formal definition of the definite Integral

> $$ \int_0^3 \left(x^2 +2\right)  dx.$$

I have

$\Delta x = \frac 3n,\ x_i^* = \frac {3i}n \\f(x_i) = (\frac {3i}n)^2 +2 $

Express $$ \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_i^*)\ \Delta x $$

in closed form, the answer will be in terms of $n$

The part i am stuck on is getting the constants out front of the $\sum$ sign.

I've plugged $x_i^* $ into $ f(x)$ and got $\frac {9i^2 + 2n}{n^2} $

but then i cant really figure out a way to isolate $i$ behind the $\sum$

Comment: Can you simplify (plug into $f$ and factor out anything that doesn't depend on $i$)?

Comment: @Ian $x_i*$ is $\frac{3i}n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
$$
 \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)\ \Delta x=\frac {27}{n^3} \sum_{i=1}^n i^2+ \frac {6}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1
$$ then use
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$ which is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16) to get, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i^*)\ \Delta x \to 15
$$

Comment: Quick question, where did the $ \frac6n$ come from?

Comment: so the ending equation for Rn should be $\frac{27((n+1)(2n+1)))}{n^2} $ correct?

Comment: Rather:$\frac{27(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2}\sim \frac{27\times2}6=9.$ Then you add $6$.

Comment: @impact_sv1 tell me if it is ok for you. Thanks.

Comment: that worked ! Thanks dude!