# Discrete Mathematics: If $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$, then $(ab-cd)^2 \leq (a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How would I prove this? I started by expanding the terms, but afterwards I am not sure what more to do to proceed.

Comment: Welcome. Geometrically, your inequality is interpreted as $\forall \theta\in \Bbb R, |\sin\theta|\leq 1$. I believe you should do geometry rather than discrete math here

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319560/geometric-proof-brahmagupta-fibonacci-identity

Comment: Do not remove your question after receiving answers to it, please

Answer (score 5):

Let's use your method. Let's expand the terms and we get

$a^2b^2 + c^2d^2 -2abcd \leq a^2b^2 + a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2d^2$

$\iff -2abcd \leq a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 $

$\iff a^2d^2 + b^2c^2 +2abcd \geq 0 $

$\iff (ad + bc)^2 \geq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the pair of vectors $(a,c)$ and $(b,-d)$ (assuming the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: This solution is eloquent(+1) but over-kill at the same time.
See the answer of @scarface