# What will be the formula of $2^2 + 4^2 + \dots + n^2$?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I'm trying to understand how to calculate $2^2 + 4^2 + \dots + n^2$. I've only succeed to upper bound it by $\dfrac {n^3} 2$. My goal is to say that it is $\Theta (n^3)$.

Thank you

Comment: What is  2^2+4^2+…+17^2 ?

Comment: Use [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/proof-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16).

Comment: Perhaps it's really a duplicate, but I don't understand the general term of the summation: why is $3^2$ missing? Is he summing over just the even numbers? If so, why does the sum end with $n^2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{hint}$ 
your series is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(2k)^2 = 4\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 = ?
$$
(Assuming that its squaring the even numbers - add more terms so we can see what the true series is)

Comment: Im guessing you meant the sigma to n/2 right ? 
I've did the calculation and i got it is ((n³∕2)+n²+(n²/2)+n))/3.
i guess now i can say the limit is n^3

Comment: ah, so that $n^2$ makes sense now. But yes you can sum up if $n$ is even.