# Finding a Riemann sum for $f(x)=\frac{x^2}4+2$ over $[0,2]$.

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form, riemann-sum

Consider the function f(x)= (x^2/4)+2.

Calculate Rn for f(x)= (x^2/4)+2 on the interval [0,2] and write your answer as a function of n without any summation signs.

Rn= ???

lim{n->infty} Rn= ???

i know its based on the property:
∫f(x)dx from ([a,b] =lim{n→∞} [∑ f(xi) Δx]
where Δx= (a-b)/n    and xi= (a+nΔx)

did i do it right?

Comment: Use `$ ... $` around your formulas to get them to render properly. For more info see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may recall [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/prove-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16):

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6, \quad n\ge1.
> $$

One may  then consider
$$
R_n=\frac2n\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{k^2}{n^2}+2 \right).
$$