# How do i simplify the following: $\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2+1)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I want to simplify

> $$\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2+1)$$

without a summation sign in the answer. How can I do this?

I can't work out how to simplify this expression. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Use this formula: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/prove-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Have you tried with $n = 3$ or $4$, and seen what happens? @AlexisOlson That's unnecessary, really. The answer is much simpler than that.

Comment: Oh wow. It's a minus sign. That does make things simpler.

Comment: Hint: you can distribute the summation so that you have two sums of constants and two sums with variable dependence (of the form $\Sigma 3i^2$). Notice that a lot of the terms with variable dependence cancel

Answer (score 3):

Well the obvious first step will to try to see if we can combine terms:

$\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2+1)=$

$(3\cdot1^2 + 4) + \sum_{k=2}^n (3k^2+4) - \sum_{k=2}^n (3k^2+1) - [3(n+1)^2 + 1]=$

$(3\cdot1^2 + 4)+\sum_{k=2}^n[(3k^2+4)- (3k^2+1)] - [3(n+1)^2 + 1]$

and see what happens.  As it turns out a *lot* happens.  (All of it good.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Sometimes it helps to write the terms of a sum so you're not just looking at symbols. The sum is
\begin{align*}
(3 \cdot 1^2 + 4) + &(3 \cdot 2^2 + 4) + (3 \cdot 3^2 + 4) + \cdots + (3 \cdot n^2 + 4) \\
- \Big[ &(3 \cdot 2^2 + 1) + (3 \cdot 3^2 + 1) + \cdots + (3 \cdot n^2 + 1) + (3 \cdot (n+1)^2 + 1)\Big].
\end{align*}

Can you see how to simplify that?

Answer (score 0):

That solves it. Expand the terms .....
  [image]

Comment: The answer is absolutely correct. So why is the answer downvoted??

Comment: Someone probably downvoted because they didn't like that you posted a picture instead of typing in MathJax. Don't let it get to you too much!

Comment: I upvoted. Try to learn MathJax; it does all the fancy formatting for us.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{j=2}^{n+1} (3j^2+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{j=1}^{n} (3(j+1)^2+1)$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} (3(i+1)^2+1)=\sum_{i=1}^n (3i^2+4) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} 3i^2+6i+4$$
$$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} -6i=-6\frac{n}{2}(n+1)=-3n(n+1)$$