# Evaluating limit from definition of integral

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

I created a formula that uses rectangles to approximate the area under a curve. For this instance, the answer to this problem should be equal to the area under the parabola $y=x^2$ from $[0, 2]$, which is $8/3$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 2n \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{4l^2}{n^2}$$

I don't know how to evaluate this limit, though.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for editing my proble, bye_world

Comment: No problem.$\ $

Answer (score 2):

Using the [sum of squares formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/prove-that-sum-limits-k-1nk2-fracnn12n16):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{4l^2}{n^2}
=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8}{n^3} \color{blue}{\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} l^2}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8}{n^3} \color{blue}{\frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}}$$

As $n\to\infty$, this limit will approach the ratio of the highest powers of $n$: $16/6 = 8/3$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8}{n^3} \frac{n(n-1)(2n-1)}{6}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{16n^3 - 24n^2 + 8n}{6n^3}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{8n^2 - 12n + 4}{3n^2}$$

Comment: Perfect, this was exactly what I was looking for. This solution doesn't use calculus.

Comment: November 1, 2016: the day limits stopped being part of calculus. ;-)

Comment: Well, a solution that doesn't use integrals. lol

Answer (score 0):

Let $S_n:=\sum_{l=1}^nl^2$. We have $S_{n}-S_{n-1}=n^2$, which is a quadratic polynomial, and $S_n$ must be a cubic polynomial.

Assume $S_n\approx an^3$ and lower powers of $n$. Then

$$S_n-S_{n-1}\approx an^3-a(n-1)^3\approx an^3-an^3+3an^2$$ and lower order terms.

Then $a=\frac13$ and your limit is $\frac83$.