# How can I prove that the following limit is equal to $ \frac{1}{3} $

Tags: calculus

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2 $$

I have noticed a similarity to $ \frac{1}{n^3}\int_{0}^{n}k^2dk=\frac{1}{3} $.

Comment: It's a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 x^2\,dx$.

Comment: I want to prove using only limits concepts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

Use that $$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{ n \left( n+1 \right)  \left( 2\,n+1 \right)}{6} $$

Comment: And how can I prove this equation?

Comment: use induction for $n$

Comment: @Torres Lot's of proofs can also be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48080/145141).

Answer (score 6):

Using

$$\frac{1}{n^3}\int_{0}^{n}x^2~\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{3}$$

We can squeeze,

$$\frac{1}{n^3}\int_{0}^{n}x^2~\mathrm dx-\frac1n<\frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=0}^nk^2<\frac{1}{n^3}\int_{0}^{n}x^2~\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Damn.. so fast. :-P +1

Comment: But still keep in mind that OP need an elementary limit answer, that is a bit overflowing

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra What are you even talking about?  I'm multi-tasking, playing a game with some friends and answer integral questions on the side :P

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra Mmm... I do not think it is so overflowing.  One can derive the inequalities directly from graphing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this
$$k^3-(k-1)^3=3k^2-3k+1.$$
Adding this from $1$ to $n$, the sum telescopes and
$$n^3=3\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-3\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1.$$
Alternatively
$$1=\frac3{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2-\frac3{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk+
\frac1{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^n1.\tag{*}$$
Obviously
$$0\le\sum_{k=1}^n k\le n^2$$
so
$$0\le\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k\le \frac1n.$$
Therefore
$$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k\to 0.$$
Similarly,
$$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n 1\to 0.$$
From $(*)$ then
$$\frac3{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\to 1.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> **$\ds{\LARGE\left.a\right)}$**

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{3}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n^{3}}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\pars{k^{\overline{2}} + k^{\overline{1}}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + 1}^{\overline{3}}/3 +
\pars{n + 1}^{\overline{2}}/2 - 1^{\overline{3}}/2 -
1^{\overline{2}}/2 \over n^{3}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + 1}n\pars{n - 1}/3 + \pars{n + 1}n/2 \over n^{3}} =
\bbx{1 \over 3}
\end{align}

> **$\ds{\LARGE\left.b\right)}$**. With
>   [Stolz-Ces$\mrm{\grave{a}}$ro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem):

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n^{3}}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n + 1}k^{2} - \sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{2} \over \pars{n + 1}^{3} - n^{3}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{n + 1}^{2} \over 3n^{2} + 3n + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 3}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{\pars{1 + 1/n}^{2} \over
1 + 1/n + 1/\pars{3n^{2}}} = \bbx{1 \over 3}
\end{align}