# Double Summation With Linked Indexes

Tags: summation, power-series

There is this summation:  $$\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j$$
and the answer is: $$\frac{1}{3} (n+1) (n+2) (n+15)$$

My question is how do you go from the summation to only the equation with n's.

Comment: please accept my answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner sum is an arithmetic series. The sum is the average element $0.5(n+10+i)$ times the number of elements ($n+10+1-i$):
$$\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j = 0.5(n+10+i)(n+10+1-i)$$
Plugging this into the summation gives:
$$\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j = \sum_{i=10}^{n+10} 0.5(n+10+1-i)(n+10+i)$$
This is a difficult sum, but you can expand the factors:
$$\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}\sum_{j=i}^{n+10} j = \sum_{i=10}^{n+10} (0.5n^2+10.5n+55)+0.5\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}i-0.5\sum_{i=10}^{n+10}i^2$$
The first term is $(n+1)(0.5n^2 + 10.5n +55)$. The second term is again an arithmetic sequence that simplifies to $0.25(n+10+10)(n+10+1-10)$. For the last term you can use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16) to get:
$$-0.5\left(\frac{1}{6}(n+10)(n+10+1)(2(n+10)+1) - \frac{1}{6}9(9+1)(2\cdot9+1)\right)$$
Now just sum the terms and simplify to obtain your result.

Comment: Why would the last term have two parts to it?

Comment: @BobJoe I first sum from $1$ to  $n+10$, and then subtract the first 9 terms