# $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + n^2$ Is/what is the name of this progression / series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + n^2$$

Is this a series? or can it be converted to a series?
What's its name?
Is there a formula? ($F_n$?)

Thanks. (I'm pretty novice when it comes to mathematical notation btw)

Context: I saw a question where you were presented with a square grid, and asked how many squares you could make (this includes each grid cell, but also the whole grid is a square shape, and then there are bigger squares made up of multiple grid cells etc).
I figured out that the answer follows the pattern above, and was looking for a full general solution for any grid size.

Comment: Limit is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: @QC_QAOA ${\infty = \frac{\pi^2}{6}}$?

Comment: The answer is ζ(-2) which can use [Ramunajun Summation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) to find a divergence based value. I wonder what it is...

Comment: Faulhaber's partial sums : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: It's the sum of squares sequence. The formula is $\frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}$.

Comment: Must be tired @riemann'spointynose for some reason I saw a minus in there. And apt name for this question

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_powers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of First $n$ Squares Equals $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum
$$
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 ... + n^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2
$$
is called the *sum of the first $n$ squares*. There is a formula for this given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$
as is shown in the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48080/sum-of-first-n-squares-equals-fracnn12n16).

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are the Square Pyramidal numbers.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquarePyramidalNumber.html