# Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, visualization

I recently proved that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k \right)^2$$

using mathematical induction.  I'm interested if there's an intuitive explanation, or even a combinatorial interpretation of this property. I would also like to see any other proofs.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/generalisation-of-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-bigg-sum-limits-k

Comment: Look at this http://www.takayaiwamoto.com/Sums_and_Series/sumcube_1.html

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120674 for remarks about proofs "not using induction".

Comment: I merged the three existing posts which covered exactly this question, as each post had different interesting answers which should not be lost.  I also deleted redundant comments, and comments about closing posts as duplicates.  This [fourth question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61798/generalisation-of-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-bigg-sum-limits-k) is not considered a duplicate.

Comment: Since this question is asked frequently, it has been added to the [list of Generalizations of Common questions.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions)  It has been kept seperate from [the version which does use induction.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)

Comment: I know both formulae. I had never realized one was the square of the other...Thank you for asking the question.

Comment: Wikipedia calls this [Nicomachus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicomachus%27s_theorem) (from [Nicomachus of Gerasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicomachus_of_Gerasa), also mentioned in some answers below). On Wikipedia, also see [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Stare at the following image, taken from this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/24828#24828), long enough:

[image: Proof that the sum of the cubes is the square of the sum]

Comment: original link: http://users.tru.eastlink.ca/~brsears/math/oldprob.htm#s32

Comment: The fact that there are $k$ blocks (or $\frac{1}{2}+k{-}1+\frac{1}{2}$ blocks) of $k\times k$ size is based on the fact that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}=k(k{-}1)/2$.  That is, $(k{-}1)/2$ blocks on top $(k{-}1)/2$ on the left and $1$ block at the corner (totaling to $k$).  Perhaps I am being picky or slow, but I don't see this as obvious from the image. Beyond that, it is a nice proof-without-words.

Comment: I have put the details of the proof corresponding to this image in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-li/61544#61544) since the comment area was too small.

Comment: I don’t think this is a proof free from induction.

Comment: This only proves the assertion for $n=5$. If someone is to accept its validity for general $n$, then it is clearly not induction-free.

Comment: That only shows you haven't stared at the image long enough...

Comment: I had to cheat and look it up but once you see it you can't miss it.  I'm ashamed of myself...

Answer (score 48):

I don't know if this is intuitive, but it is graphic.

[image: Graphic proof that the sum of cubes is the square of the sum of first powers]

On the outer edge of each $(k{+}1){\times}k$ block there are $k$ pairs of products each of which total to $k^2$.  Thus, the outer edge sums to $k^3$, and  the sum of the whole array is therefore $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3$.

The array is the matrix product
$$
\left[\begin{array}{r}0\\1\\2\\\vdots\\n\end{array}\right]\bullet\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}1&2&3&\cdots&n\end{array}\right]
$$
Therefore, the sum of the elements of the array is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^nk\;\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)^2$.

Therefore, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)^2$

Comment: If we forget the first line of the matrix (which is zero and which is only used to make pairs with the diagonal coefficients), then I like the fact we can put this answer in parallel with the coloured rectangles above and below, and we get another partition of each colored area (each coefficient of the matrix gives a rectangle of a certain area), which explains why each L-shaped area is $k^3$.

Comment: However, each L-shape coefficient has the same factor $k$, which means it proves "each L-shaped area is $k^3$" by the same proof that $2 \times \sum_{j=0}^k j = (0+k) + (1+k-1) + ... + (k-1+1) + (k+0) = (k+1) \times k$, which makes it really close to the coloured rectangles above and below.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I use both ideas in [another answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-li/61762#61762).

Comment: I don't mind. I simply find it less aesthetic to need to use $\sum\limits_{j=1}^k\;j=k(k+1)/2$ or that $(k(k+1)/2)^2-(k(k-1)/2)^2=k^3$ in an intuitive proof.

Answer (score 37):

I believe this illustration is due to [Anders Kaseorg](http://www.quora.com/Anders-Kaseorg):

[image: Visual proof by block-stacking]

Answer (score 34):

Can you get the intuition explanation from the following two pictures?[EDIT: the following is essentially the same as Mariano's answer. He didn't mentioned the first picture though.]

[image]
[image]

The images are from [Brian R Sears](http://users.tru.eastlink.ca/~brsears/math/oldprob.htm#s32).

Comment: nice, but already posted (linked) by Mariano

Answer (score 27):

Here's another version of this "proof without words".  This is the case $n=4$.

[image]

There are 1 $1 \times 1$, 2 $2 \times 2$, 3 $3 \times 3$, ... squares, for a total area of $1^3 + 2^3 + \ldots + n^3$.  For even $k$, two of the $k \times k$ squares overlap in a $k/2 \times k/2$ square, but this
just balances out a $k/2 \times k/2$ square that is left out, so the total is the area of 
a square of side $1 + 2 + \ldots + n$.

Answer (score 26):

There's this nice picture from the Wikipedia entry on the [squared triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number):

[image]

The left side shows that $1 + 2 + 3$ forms a triangle and so that squaring it produces a larger triangle made up of $1+2+3$ copies of the original triangle.  The right side has $1(1^2) + 2(2^2) + 3(3^2) = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3$.  The coloring shows why the two sides are equal.

There are several other references for combinatorial proofs and geometric arguments on the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a direct algebraic proof. $$\sum_{k=1}^n(k^3-k^2)=2\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot\frac{k(k-1)}2=2\sum_{k=1}^nk\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}l=2\sum_{1\leqslant l<k\leqslant n}kl=\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)^2-\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$$

Here's also a nice analogue of this calculation:

$$\int_0^x t^3dt  = 2 \int_0^x t \cdot \frac{t^2}2dt = 2\int_0^x t dt\int_0^t udu = \left(\int_0^x t\right)^2 \,.$$

Just to emphasize that the proof relies on the substitution rule, Fubini's theorem, and the discrete version of $\int_0^x t dt= \frac{x^2}2$, but not on induction directly.

Comment: But you're relying on a fact that is (often) proved with induction?

Comment: Definitely. But one that could credibly pretend not to rely on induction. I very much like the last paragraph of this answer: [Must we use induction to prove a statement for all integers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/120807/43288)

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1819703/43288

Comment: i dont understand k^3-k^2 gives us 2k^3?

Answer (score 22):

Each colored area is $k^3$ as a difference of two areas: $S_k^2 - S_{k-1}^2$.

[image]

[image]

---

The detailed proof which comes with the drawing is the following.

For any positive integer $k$, we define:
 $$S_i = \sum_{j=1}^{i} j$$

We first notice:
$$S_i^2 = S_i^2 - S_0^2= \sum_{k=1}^{i} \left(S_k^2 - S_{k-1}^2\right)$$

The expected result finally comes from:
 $$S_k^2 - S_{k-1}^2 = k \left(k+2  S_{k-1}\right) = k\left(k+k\left(k-1\right)\right)=k^3$$

Comment: So essentially, you are using the fact that $$\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\;j\right)^2-\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\;j\right)^2=k^3$$ to justify the diagram which is supposed to prove that fact intuitively.

Comment: As you mentioned in another answer, this is where the diagram is the least intuitive. However, if you cannot picture $k^3$ on a 2D-plane, then you need another representation as a difference of areas.

Comment: As soon as you know $S_k = \sum_{j=1}^k j = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, I find it more intuitive to figure out each colored area is $k^3$ on this diagram than to figure it out by counting squares **plus two rectangles** *when $k$ is even*.

Answer (score 21):

The formula is due to Nicomachus of Gerasa.  There is a nice discussion of ways to prove it at [this n-category cafe post](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/07/nichomachus_of_gerasa.html), including a bijective proof and some visual / "geometric" proofs.

Answer (score 19):

Several [visual proofs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_without_words) of this indentity are collected in the book
Roger B. Nelsen: [Proofs without Words](http://books.google.com/books?id=cyyhZr-SffcC)
starting from [p.84](http://books.google.com/books?id=cyyhZr-SffcC&pg=PA84).

Although several of these proofs can still be considered inductive, I thought it might be interesting to mention them.

Original sources are given on [p. 147](http://books.google.com/books?id=cyyhZr-SffcC&pg=PA147):

- 84 Mathematical Gazette, vol. 49, no. 368 (May 1965), p. 199. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612319)
- 85 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 50, no. 2 (March 1977), p. 74. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689727)
- 86 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 58, no. 1 (Jan. 1985), p. 11. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690228)
- 87 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 62, no. 4 (Oct. 1989), p. 259. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689765)
- 87 Mathematical Gazette, vol. 49, no. 368 (May 1965), p. 200. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3612319)
- 88 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 63, no. 3 (June 1990), p. 178. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691139)
- 89 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 62, no. 5 (Dec. 1989), p. 323. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689485)
- 90 Mathematics Magazine, vol. 65, no. 3 (June 1992), p. 185. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2691330)

Comment: Great collections. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I find a quite funny proof!

Observe that
$$n^3=n^2\times n$$
By using the identity $xy=\left(\dfrac{x+y}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right)^2$, we get
$$n^2\times n=\left(\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{n^2-n}{2}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n k\right)^2-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k\right)^2$$
Therefore, $$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\sum_{r=1}^n \left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^r k\right)^2-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{r-1} k\right)^2\right]=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n k\right)^2-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{0} k\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$$
After changing the variables, we get
$$\boxed{\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2}$$

Comment: VERY VERY VERY NICE!!!!! This is a wonderfully elegant proof (+1)

Answer (score 17):

You know, $\sum_0^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. Differentiate both sides once, $\sum_1^n kx^{k-1}=\frac{x^n(nx-n-1)+1}{x^2-2x+1}$. Now taking $\lim_{x\to1}$ both sides and then squaring the result will give you the expression on the RHS. You can further differentiate $\sum_0^n x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ until you get $k^3$ inside the expression, take limit again you will get the same result as of $\left(\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^n(nx-n-1)+1}{x^2-2x+1}\right)^2$. You can also prove it using telescopic series.

Comment: why does the assumption hold? this is usually proved using induction...

Comment: what assumption??

Comment: I guess Auke means $\sum_{0}^{n} x^k=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$.

Comment: LHS is a geometric series. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: @Auke: one can also prove it like this - let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^nx^k$, then $f(x) - xf(x)$ is:
$$
\begin{align}
1+&x+x^2+\dots+x^n
\\
&-
\\
&x+x^2+\dots+x^n+x^{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
which is $1-x^{n+1}$. Hence
$$
  (1-x)f(x) = 1-x^{n+1}
$$
as needed.

Answer (score 16):

$f(n)=1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3$

$f(n-1)=1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+(n-1)^3$

$f(n)-f(n-1)=n^3$

if $g(n)= (1+2+3+4+\cdots+n)^2$  then

$$g(n)-g(n-1)=(1+2+3+4+\cdots+n)^2-(1+2+3+4+\cdots+(n-1))^2$$

using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

$$\begin{align}g(n)-g(n-1)&=\\
&=[(1+\dots+n)+(1+\dots +(n-1))][(1+\dots+ n)-(1+\dots+(n-1)]\\
&=[2(1+2+3+4+\cdots+(n-1))+n]n\\
&=\left(2\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n\right)n\\
&==(n(n-1)+n)n\\
&=n^3
\end{align}$$

$f(n)-f(n-1)=g(n)-g(n-1)=n^3$ for all $n$ and if $f(0)=g(0)$ then

$f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are equal and we can write
$$1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3=(1+2+3+4+\cdots+n)^2$$

Comment: This is really an inductive proof — it’s rearranged to push the induction into the general fact implicitly appealed to at the end, “if $f(n)-f(n-1) = g(n)-g(n-1)$ for all $n$, and if $f(0)=g(0)$, then $f$ and $g$ are equal”, but it remains extremely close to the direct inductive proof.  (Unlike a few other answers, which do technically require an appeal to induction, but are different enough from a direct inductive proof that they shed a different light on the fact.)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine  Thanks a lot for comment. I updated my answer

Answer (score 15):

The sum of a degree $n$ polynomial $f(n)$ will be a degree $n+1$ polynomial $S(n)$ for $n \geq 0$ and both polynomials can be extended (maintaining the relation $S(n)-S(n-1) = f(n)$) to negative $n$. 
To verify that the formula for $\Sigma k^3$ is correct one need only test it for any 5 distinct values of $n$, but the structure of the answer can be predicted algebraically using the continuation to negative $n$.

If $S(n) = (1^3 + 2^3 + \dots n^3)$ is the polynomial that satisfies $S(n)-S(n-1) = n^3$ and $S(1)=1$, then one can calculate from that equation that $S(0)=S(-1)=0$ and $S(-n-1)=S(n)$ for all negative $n$, so that $S$ is symmetric around $-1/2$.  The vanishing at 0 and -1 implies that $S(t)$ is divisible as a polynomial by $t(t+1)$. The symmetry implies that $S(t)$ is a function (necessarily a polynomial) of $t(t+1)$.

$S(t)$ being of degree 4, this means $S(n) = a (n)(n+1) + b((n^2 +n)^2$ for constants $a$ and $b$.  Summation being analogous to integration (and equal to it in a suitable limit), they have to agree on highest degree terms.  Here it forces $b$ to be $1/4$ to match $\int x^3 = x^4/4$.  Computing the sum at a single point  such as $n=1$ determines $a$, which is zero.

Similar reasoning shows that $S_k(n)$ is divisible as a polynomial by $n(n+1)$ for all $k$. For odd $k$, $S_k(n)$ is a polynomial in $n(n+1)$.

Answer (score 12):

We know that $$A=\sum_1^n k^3=\frac{1}{4}n^4+\frac{1}{2}n^3+\frac{1}{4}n^2$$ and $$B=\sum_1^n k=\frac{1}{2}n^2+\frac{1}{2}n$$ $A-B^2=0$. :)

Comment: If you are presenting this proof,write it nicely. $A=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ and $B=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$,obviously $A=B^2$

Comment: @avatar: Dear Avatar; I will. Your proof is great and it looks analytically. Thanks. :-)

Comment: sorry, if you felt that i was being rude.

Comment: @avatar: Your proof lights mine. No Problem at all. WELCOME Avatar. :)  :)

Answer (score 9):

One way to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n i \bigg)^2$$
is to add up the entries in the multiplication tables, but first we need to show that
$$1+2+3+\dots+n+\dots+3+2+1 = n^2$$
For this, see the image below (n=7)[image]
$$7^2=\color{green}{1+2+3+4+5+6+7}\color{red}{+6+5+4+3+2+1}$$
Next, consider the standard multiplication table that we are all familiar with.The graphic shows the table up to the 9s.

[image]

We can add up the entries in any order that we wish.
One way would be to add up a series of Ls (the 6th L ($L_6$) is highlighted in yellow).
$$\begin{align}
L_6 &= 6+12+18+24+30+36+30+24+18+12+6\\
&=6(1+2+3+4+5+6+5+4+3+2+1)\\
&=6(6^2)\\
&=6^3
\end{align}$$
And the sum of all the entries in the table becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^n L_i = \sum_{i=1}^n i^3$$
Alternatively, we could just add up each row. The 6th row ($R_6$) would be
$$\begin{align}
R_6 &= 6+12+18+24+30+36+42+48+54\\
&= 6(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9)\\
&= 6\sum_{i=1}^9 i
\end{align}$$
And the sum of all the entries becomes
$$\sum_{i=1}^n R_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \bigg(i\sum_{j=1}^n j\bigg)=\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^n j\bigg)\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n i\bigg)=\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n i\bigg)^2$$
Thus we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n L_i = \sum_{i=1}^n R_i=\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n i\bigg)^2$$

Comment: Nice, you could rewrite that as an algebraic proof. It would be similar to my answer, but without subtracting $\sum k^2$.

Answer (score 8):

Chance would have it that I stumbled* upon this article today:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/03/04/nichomachuss-theorem/

It seems to answer your question.

(* That is, [@AlgebraFact](https://twitter.com/#!/AlgebraFact) on Twitter posted a link)

Answer (score 8):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#Faulhaber_polynomials

If $p$ is odd, then $1^p+2^p+3^p+\cdots+n^p$ is a polynomial function of $a=1+2+3+\cdots+n$.  If $p=3$, then then the sum is $a^2$; if $p=5$ then it's $(4a^3-a^2)/3$, and so on.

Comment: And $a$ is always a factor of $p$.

Answer (score 8):

**Here's a simple bijective proof of a different sort**:

Consider a staircase with $n$ steps, built out of $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ blocks. In other words, take the set $\{(i,j) \in \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: i + j \leq n, i > 0, j > 0\}$.

Then $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$ is the number of ordered pairs $(B_1,B_2)$ of blocks.

And $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ is the number of ordered $4$-tuples $(k,b_1,b_2,b_3)$, where $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $b_1$ is along the $k$-th diagonal $b_1 \in \{(k+1-j,j): j \in \{1,\ldots,k\}\}$, and $b_2$ is along the bottom $b_2 \in \{(j,1): j \in \{1,\ldots, k\}\}$ and $b_3$ is along the left side $b_3 \in \{(1,j): j \in \{1, \ldots, k\}\}$.

**The bijection**:

Given an ordered tuple $(k,b_1,b_2,b_3)$, let $A_1 = b_1$ and let $A_2$ given by $b_2$ and $b_3$ as its $x$ and $y$ coordinates, so if $b_2 = (i,1)$ and $b_3 = (1,j)$ then $A_2 = (i,j)$.

Case 1: $A_2$ is on or below the $k$-th diagonal. Then let $(B_1, B_2) = (A_1, A_2)$.

Case 2: $A_2$ is above the $k$-the diagonal. Then let $A_2'$ be the reflection across the $k$-th diagonal of $A_2$. That is, if $A_2 = (i,j)$ then $A_2' = (k+1-j,k+1-i)$. Then let $(B_1, B_2) = (A_2', A_1)$.

*The inverse*:

To get the inverse, take whichever of $B_1$ and $B_2$ is on a higher diagonal (i.e. has greater sum of its coordinates), taking $B_1$ in case of ties, and let that be $b_1$ and let $k$ be the sum of the coordinates of $b_1$.

Case 1: If $B_1$ is used: Take $B_2$ and let $b_2$ and $b_3$ be given by points with the same the $x$- and $y$-coordinates, respectively, as $B_2$.

Case 2: If $B_2$ is used: Take $B_1'$ (i.e. the reflection across the $k$-th diagonal, as above) and let $b_2$ and $b_3$ be given by points with the same the $x$- and $y$-coordinates, respectively, as $B_1'$.

Answer (score 7):

The square in the identity is the area of the triangle below, while the cubes are the areas of the trapezoidal layers, with heights $k = 1, 2, \cdots, n$ 
[image: TriangleWithHeight 1+2+..+n]

The trapezoids have area $k^3$ because their height equals $k$ and the $\text{width}_{\text{atHalfHeight}}$ consists of $k$ diagonals with width $k$:
[image: Trapezoidal layer with height = k and width = k^2]

The total of the triangle is its squared height $(1 + 2 + \cdots + n)^2$, because this triangle can be turned into a square: 
[image: The triangle cut in two and recomposed as a square.]

Therefore: 
$(1 + 2 + \cdots + n)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ , $\blacksquare$

Comment: Is there some mathematical explanation, why the triangle can be turned into square?

Answer (score 6):

[image: square triangular proof without words]

This is about the same proof as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/61494#61494), the presentation is a bit different though. This is another way to make $k^3$ appear than what was shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/61483#61483), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/61506#61506) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/61544#61544).

Answer (score 4):

For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$
$$(k+1)^4=k^4+4k^3++6k^2+4k+1$$
therefore
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)^4=\sum_{k=1}^nk^4+4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+4\sum_{k=1}^nk+\sum_{k=1}^n1$$
which is equivalent to 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^4+(n+1)^4-1=\sum_{k=1}^nk^4+4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3+6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2+2n(n+1)+n$$
After simplifications we obtain
$$4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=(n+1)^4-1-2n(n+1)-n-6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=n^4+4n^3+4n^2+n-6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2$$
Using 
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\hspace{0.2cm}\text{and}\hspace{0.2cm}\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
we get
$$4\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=n^4+4n^3+4n^2+n-6\sum_{k=1}^nk^2\\=n^4+4n^3+4n^2+n-n(n+1)(2n+1)\\=n^4+2n^3+n^2=n^2(n+1)^2$$
Finally
$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}=\Big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Big)^2=\Big(\sum_{k=1}^nk\Big)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

We begin by writing $k^3$ in a more clever fashion: $k^3 = k(k-1)(k-2) + 3k^2 - 2k$ :

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 = \sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1)(k-2) + 3k^2 -2k$$

Distributing the summation and adjusting our indices we obtain: $$ \sum_{k=3}^n k(k-1)(k-2) + \sum_{k=0}^n 3k^2 - \sum_{k=0}^n 2k$$

Notice, $$k(k-1)(k-2) = \frac {k!}{(k-3)!}$$
Now we have 
$$\sum_{k=3}^n \frac {k!}{(k-3)!} + \sum_{k=0}^n 3k^2 - \sum_{k=0}^n 2k$$
Notice that we have nearly obtained the binomial expansion of K choose 3, all we need to do is divide by 3! So we offset this by also taking the product of 3!
$$\sum_{k=3}^n \frac {k!}{(k-3)!} = 3!\sum_{k=3}^n \frac {k!}{(k-3)!3!} = 3!\sum_{k=3}^n\binom{k}{3} = 3!\binom{n+1}{4}$$
We have now obtained 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^3 = 3!\binom{n+1}{4} + 3\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 - 2\sum_{k=0}^n k$$
Focusing solely on the right-hand side we have
$$6\biggl(\frac {(n+1)!}{(n-3)!4!}\biggr) + 3\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 - 2\sum_{k=0}^n k$$ 
Assuming we already know the sum of the sequence of integers and squared integers (the 2 sums we have left) we have 
$$ \frac {(n+1)(n)(n-1)(n-2)}{4} + 3\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - 2\frac {n(n+1)}{2}$$
Generating common denominators and with a bit of algebra we now have
$$ \frac {n^4-2n^3-n^2+2n+4n^3+6n^2+2n-4n^2-4n}{4}$$
Combining like-terms we have reached our solution:
$$ \frac {n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4} = \biggl(\sum_{k=0}^n k\biggr)^2$$

Answer (score 3):

I was just playing around,
and I am probably the
47,000,000th person
to do this,
and this is undoubtedly
equivalent to
another answer
but, anyway...

Use
$\sum_{i=1}^n i
=i(i+1)/2$
and
$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i)^2
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2
+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} a_ia_j
$.

$\begin{array}\\
(\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} ij\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+2\sum_{i=1}^ni\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+2\sum_{i=1}^ni\cdot i(i-1)/2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+\sum_{i=1}^ni^2(i-1)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+\sum_{i=1}^n(i^3-i^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n i^2
+\sum_{i=1}^ni^3-\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni^3\\
\end{array}
$

It was a pleasant surprise that
$\sum_{i=1}^ni^2
$
cancelled out.

Answer (score 2):

After many years I still think the best way to solve this kind of problem in a natural and systematic way is to view it as a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) with constants coefficients, in this case, $x_n = x_{n-1}+n^3$. The way I learnt to do so was by using characteristic polynomial but you may prefer some other method...

Answer (score 2):

To the collection of the geometric proofs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've gotta see it to believe it.

[image]

In formulas:

$$(\sum k)^2=\sum j^2 + 2 \sum_{i<j} ij =\sum_j (j^2+2 \sum_{i<j} ij)=\sum_j j(j+j(j-1))=\sum_j j(j^2)=\sum_j j^3$$

In words: we can assemble the square with side $(1+...+k)$ from
$k$ smaller squares and pairs of rectangular blocks.  If we look only at the rectangular blocks with the largest side fixed to some size $j$, they all pair up into $j-1$ "complementary" pairs (based on the size of the smaller side, pairing $1$ with $j-1$, $2$ with $j-2$,  untill $j-1$ with $j$; this is Gauss' trick), each pair of rectangles forming a $j$ by $j$ square together. Thus, together with the $j^2$ piece they assemble into a cube of side $j$.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses the same sort of reasoning as given in the [answer by zyx](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61514/760992). I show that we can get a bit more out of the recursion relation satisfied by the function $S(n)$ and their generalizations for summation of arbitrary powers, in particular that $S(t)$ (and its generalization for summations over odd powers larger than 1) contains a factor $t^2 (1+t)^2$. This then immediately establishes the result.

We start with defining the functions $S_k(n)$:

$$ S_k(n) =\sum_{r=0}^{n}r^k \tag{1}$$

where $k$ and $n$ are integers and we take $k\geq 1$ and $n\geq 0$. The functions $S_k(n)$ satisfy the recursion:

$$ S_k(n) - S_k(n-1) = n^k \tag{2}$$

This recursion together with the condition that $S_k(0) = 0$ which follows from (1), fixes the function $S_k(n)$. In particular, it follows from this that $S_k(n)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$. This means that we can lift the constraint that $n$ be an integer larger than or equal to zero and instead take $n$ to be any arbitrary real or complex number.

If we put $n = 0$ in (2) and use that $S_k(0) = 0$, we find:

$$S_k(-1) = 0$$

The function $S_k(x)$ is therefore a polynomial of degree $k+1$ which contains a factor of $x (x+1)$. Since $S_1(x)$ is a second degree polynomial, this fixes $S_1(x)$ up to a constant factor, and we can find that this factor is $\frac{1}{2}$ by using $S_k(1) = 1$, although that's not necessary to do for the purpose of this problem.

We can find a symmetry relation satisfied by $ S_k(n)$ using the recursion (2) as follows. We replace $n$ by $-n$ to obtain:

$$ S_k(-n) - S_k(-n-1) = (-1)^k n^k $$

Let’s define the function $\tilde{S}_{k}(n) = S_k(-n)$. We can then write the above recursion as:

$$ \tilde{S}_k(n+1) - \tilde{S}_k(n) = (-1)^{k+1} n^k $$

We then see that the function $(-1)^{k+1}\tilde{S}_k(n+1)$ satisfies the same recursion as the function $S_k(n)$. The value at $n = 0$ is equal to zero, because $\tilde{S}_k(1)= S_k(-1) = 0$. This means that these two functions are identical. We thus have:

$$ S_k(-x-1) = (-1)^{k+1}S_k(x)$$

The point at which $x = -x - 1$ is $x = -\frac{1}{2}$. We see that for even $k$, $S_k(x)$ is anti-symmetric w.r.t. reflection about this point, while in case of odd $k$, it is symmetric. This means that for even $k$, the function has a zero there, while for odd $k$ the derivative is zero:

$$ \begin{split}S_{2k}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) &= 0\\ S'_{2k+1}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) &= 0\end{split}$$

This fixes $S_2(x)$, because $S_2(x)$ is a third degree polynomial and it has zeros at $x = 0$, $x = 1$ and $x = -\frac{1}{2}$, so it’s proportional to $x (x+1)(2x+1)$, and demanding that $S_2(1) = 1 $ yields $S_2(x) = \frac{1}{6} x (x+1)(2x+1)$. Obtaining this expression is, however, not necessary for the purpose of this problem.

In general, we have that $S_{2k}(x)$ contains a factor of $x(x+1)(2x+1)$.
We can obtain more information about $S_k(x)$ for odd $k$ by taking the derivative of the recursion (2). This yields:

$$ S'_{2k+1}(x) - S'_{2k+1}(x-1) = (2k+1) x^{2k}$$

We then see $\frac{S'_{2k+1}(x)}{2k+1}$ satisfies the same recursion as $S_{2k}(x)$. Because both these functions are zero at $x = -\frac{1}{2}$, they are identical. The fact that $S_{2k}(x)$ is zero at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ then tells us that $ S'_{2k+1}(x)$ is zero there as well. So, we see $S_{2k+1}(x)$ has zeros at $x = 0$ and $ x = 1$ of multiplicity of at least $2$, so $S_{2k+1}(x)$ contains a factor of $x^2 (x+1)^2$.

In particular, since $S_3(x)$ is a fourth degree polynomial, we see that it is proportional to $x^2(x+1)^2$, so it's proportional to $ S_1(x)^2$. And since $ S_k(1) =1 $for all $k$, we have $S_3(x) = S_1(x)^2$.