# Prove that $ a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+\cdots+a_{l}^{3}=\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{l}\right)^{2} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, divisor-sum

> Let $ d_{1}, d_{2}, \ldots, d_{l}$ be all positive divisors of a positive integer $n$. For
> each $i=1,2, \ldots, l$ denote by $a_{i}$ the number of positive divisors of $d_{i}$. Then
> $
> a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+\cdots+a_{l}^{3}=\left(a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{l}\right)^{2}
> $

**Solution**. hint says, we have to use this but I am not getting why these both are true ???

$
\begin{aligned}
a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{l} &=\sum_{d \mid n} \tau(d)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1+\tau\left(p_{i}\right)+\cdots+\tau\left(p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}\right)\right) \\
a_{1}^{3}+a_{2}^{3}+\cdots+a_{l}^{3} &=\sum_{d \mid n} \tau(d)^{3}=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(1+\tau\left(p_{i}\right)^{3}+\cdots+\tau\left(p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}\right)^{3}\right)
\end{aligned}
$

Comment: What is $\tau$? Sum of divisors or something?

Comment: @BenjaminWang  "no of divisors of n"

Comment: And what are the $p_i$? Presumably having to do with prime power factorization of $n$ but this should be clarified in the problem.

Comment: Take an arbitrary element of the first product. What does it look like, and can you make that correspond to some divisor of $n$? Hopefully you can finish from there.

Comment: Does $d_1,...,d_l$ include the trivial divisors $1$ and $n$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/216698/589

Comment: Related question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398613.

Comment: @Ishan have you studied the method that I posted? It's quite straightforward as long as you can prove multiplicativity of tau and the multiplicativity of the sum of a multiplicative function over the positive divisors of the input.

Answer (score 0):

See Proposition 1 in [Sum of Cubes is Square of Sum by Barbeau and Seraj](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5257). Here's the quoted proof:

> The proposition is clearly true for prime powers since for each prime $p$ and each natural $n$, the corresponding set of $p^{n-1}$ is
> $$\langle\tau(p^0), \tau(p^1), \ldots, \tau(p^{n-1})\rangle=\langle 1,2,\ldots,n\rangle.$$
> $\tau$ is well-known to be a multiplicative function, meaning that if $a,b$ are relatively prime integers then $\tau(ab)=\tau(a)\tau(b).$ By elementary multiplicative number theory, the functions
> \begin{align*}
> f(n)&=\sum_{d\mid n}{\tau(d)},\\
> F(n)&=\sum_{d\mid n}{[\tau(d)}]^3
> \end{align*}
> must also be multiplicative. All we need now is that $F(n)=[f(n)]^2$. Since this is already true for prime powers, the rest follows from the prime factorization of $n$ and the multiplicative property of $f$ and $F$.

The result is attributed to Liouville. Disclosure: I'm one of the authors, and I have no issues with the proof in the paper being quoted here. See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_Over_Divisors_of_Multiplicative_Function) for why the sum of a multiplicative function over divisors of the input is multiplicative. Of course, a multiplicative function to a positive integer exponent is also multiplicative.