# Intuitive/Visual proof that $(1+2+\cdots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-without-words

$$(1+2+\cdots+n)^2=1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$$

I noticed this only because $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$.

But the two things look completely different and I can't think of an intuitive reason I would have seen this connection. Something like the 'Proof Without Words' images. Or a trick I could use while expanding the right hand side to transform it to the sum of cubes.

Comment: There are two pictures on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number) Wiki article which might be of interest.

Comment: *Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482/264*

Comment: I would delete the question but we'd lose the image posted by MJD!

Comment: I reposted it at the other place too.

Comment: @genepeer: MJD has posted his answer on the other thread now. There's no need to delete your question; we'll just close it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

I think this image is due to [Anders Kaseorg](http://www.quora.com/Anders-Kaseorg).

Comment: Very pretty! How did you make the picture?

Comment: I didn't make it.  I did a search on this site for "sum of cubes", found [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/combinatorial-interpretation-of-sum-of-squares-cubes), and plucked the image out of [a deleted post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/194046/25554).

Comment: This is awesome!

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i^3 = n^3
$$

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\right)^2&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i\right)\\
&=n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)\right)\\
&=n\left(n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} n\right)\\
&=n\left(n + n(n-1)\right)\\
&=n\cdot n^2 = n^3
\end{align}$$

(This is to show that it makes *mathematically* intuitive sense)

Comment: Nice. I wasn't sure what you were doing till I saw the last sentence

Comment: It's a very nice and tricky answer, mostly because you did not use the formula $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ in your induction.