# Geometric Series Question Variable answer

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm having a bit of trouble with the answer for this question. I've found that u1 is 9p, but i cant find the common ratio.

$$\sum_{n=-3}^2{pn^2}=\;?$$

So for my series looks like this:

9p+4p+p+0+p+4p

I can add it to get 19p, but is there a way to use the geometric series formula to find the sum?

Comment: What geometric series? The finite sum there is **not** a geometric one.

Comment: Oh , my mistake then. So is there a way to find the sum with a formula, or do i just have to add each term together.

Comment: Not that I can see: you just have to sum them all up directly, imo.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Actually there is a very well-known formula for $1^2+\dots+n^2$, see here for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/combinatorial-interpretation-of-sum-of-squares-cubes

Comment: @HansLundmark I know, but there's no point in using it in cases like this, with so small a number of summands.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Of course, but the question was if  you *have* to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

$$\sum_{n=-3}^2 pn^2=9p+4p+p+0+p+4p=19p$$

...and that's pretty much all there is. The finite sum above is *not* a geometric one.