# $1^3+2^3+...+n^3= $? How I can find formula

Tags: proof-writing

$1^3+2^3+...+n^3=$ has a formula which $(1+2+3+...+n)^2 $ or $[n(n + 1)/2]^2$ . We can verify with ınduction and I know how I can prove it. How we find what is the formula...

I tried like this
$1^3+2^3+...+n^3= An^4+ Bn^3+Cn^2+Dn+E$
after a long process i found it this way
$A=-299/54,$
$B=-4/9,$
$C=107/54,$
$D=4.$
And then I tried how can show that 
But I didn't find Maybe The value of a,b,c,d is wrong 
Can I get proof of this formula in this way or another way
if we didn't know the formula, how would we get this formula

Comment: I am confused what your question is .... you apparently know that $1^3 + 2^3 + ... + n^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2$ ... and you are also able to prove it.  So what do you mean by 'How can I find the formula'?

Comment: I don't understand.  You have the formula, what's left to find?

Comment: If you want to look at the problem generally, see [Faulhaber's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula)

Comment: Side note: if you really want to do it by matching coefficients, I'd start with $n=0$.  Saves a lot of tedious algebra.

Comment: if we didn't know the formula, how would we get this formula

Comment: The constant in your expression should not be $C$.  From the pattern it should be $E$.

Comment: "*If we didn't know the formula, how would we get this formula?*"  Intuition?  Looking for patterns?  Coming up with a combinatorial interpretation of the one expression and finding an alternate way of counting the same scenario?  Drawing pictures?  There are many ways of doing this.  [See this for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/combinatorial-interpretation-of-sum-of-squares-cubes?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: [See also this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i?noredirect=1&lq=1) with some nice visual interpretations of the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coming up with a formula is often a matter of 'playing around' ... and hopefully you start to see any patterns.

So, we could just see what happens:

\begin{array}{c|c}
n&1^3+2^3+ ... +n^3\\
\hline
1&1\\
2&9\\
3&36\\
4&100\\
...&...\\
\end{array}

Well ... if you know a little about numbers, I think you'd recognize $1,9,36,100$ as $1^2,3^2,6^2$ and $10^2$ respectively ... and the $1,3,6,10,...$ clearly follows a pattern as well: $1$, $1+2$, $1+2+3$,  ...

OK, so there's your formula.

Of course, at this point it's just a hypothesis ... but when you try to prove it ... you find that you can!

Another method is to play around with the veru concepts involved. So, you could take a bunch of cubes and see if you can somehow rearrange them in some other patterns.  This is what's done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i).

And yes, you could also try your method of guessing that there might be some kind of polynomial formula for this: $An^4+Bn^3+Cn^2+Dn+E$ .... though that is taking a bit of a risk: why would it be a polynomial? Why not some exponential function, for example? And even if it is a polynomial, why wouldn't it go beyond $n^4$?

Answer (score 1):

A loose idea as to how to arrive at such formulas (albeit tedious, but most of the time works) is as follows. Let $f(x)$ be an integral polynomial of degree $d$. Let us say, we want to find a formula for $S(n)=f(0)+f(1)+\cdots +f(n)$. Knowing $\int x^d=x^{d+1}/d+1$, one guesses that the formula should be a polynomial of degree $d+1$. So write a polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $d+1$, whose coefficients are to be determined. These can be determined by writing a bunch of linear equations coming from $g(m)=S(m)$ for $0\leq m\leq d+1$. Once you have $g(x)$, attempt to prove the result using induction.

In your case, if you had guessed that the formula should be a quartic polynomial, the rest would have been easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $1^3 + \cdots + n^3$ is a $4$th degree polynomial $P(n)$ (for $n \geq 0$), you can write out $P(n) = a_4 n^4 + \cdots + a_1 n + a_0$ and solve the system of equations 
\begin{align*}
P(0) &= 0 \\
\vdots&  \\
P(4) &= 1^3 + \cdots + 4^3
\end{align*}
to find the coefficients $a_i$. It's kind of messy (and maybe that's the method you used above), and it doesn't generalize easily to sums of higher powers $1^k + \cdots + n^k$. The punchline is Faulhaber's formula, which characterizes the coefficients in terms of the Bernoulli numbers (and, accordingly, requires a bit of machinery to prove).

So, why should you believe that such a polynomial $P$ exists? In essence, you're looking for a function with $P$ with
\begin{align*}
P(n) - P(n-1) = n^3
\end{align*}
for $n \geq 1$. It's easy to note that if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $k > 0$, then $P(n) - P(n-1)$ is a polynomial of degree $k - 1$ in $n$. (The difference is clearly a polynomial of degree $\leq k$, and the coefficients of degree $k$ in $P(n)$ and $P(n-1)$ cancel.) To make this more precise, we could define an operator
\begin{align*}
(Sf)(n) &= \sum_{k=1}^n f(k)
\end{align*}
for reasonable functions $f$. Via, say, an inductive argument, we can prove that $Sf$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ for any nonzero polynomial of degree $k-1$; and, furthermore,
\begin{align*}
(Sf)(n) - (Sf)(n-1) = f(n).
\end{align*}
Thus we're effectively trying to compute $Sf$ for $f(n) = n^3$.

This sort of thing is called the finite-difference calculus, and there's a bunch of similar results on it. One particular thing I'll note is that it's often easier to work with the binomial coefficients
\begin{align*}
P_k(n) &= \binom{n}{k},
\end{align*}
which is a polynomial of degree $k$. (More technically, there's a polynomial of degree $k$ that it equals for $n\geq 0$. These have the convenient property that
\begin{align*}
P_k(n) - P_k(n-1) = P_{k-1}(n-1),
\end{align*}
whereas (as you've seen if you've tried to do the computation by hand), the corresponding result for the polynomials $n^k$ are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand 
$$\left(\frac {n(n+1)}2\right)^2=\frac 14n^2(n^2+2n+1)=\frac 14n^4+\frac 12n^3+\frac 14n^2$$
and read off $A=\frac 14,B=\frac 12,C=\frac 14,D=0,E=0$
You can also solve simultaneous equations
$$1^3=1=A1^4+B^3+C1^2+D1+E=A+B+C+D+E\\
1^3+2^3=9=A2^4+B2^3+C2^2+D2+E=16A+8B+4C+2D+E$$
and three more similar.  You should get the same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

$0=E, 1=A+B+C+D+E, 1^3+2^3=9=16A+8B+4C+2D+E,$

$ 1^3+2^3+3^3=36=81A+27B+9C+3D+E, $

and $1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3=100=256A+64B+16C+4D+E \implies$

$ E=0, 7=14A+6B+2C, 33=78A+24B+6C, $ and $96=252A+60B+12C \implies$

$12=36A+6B$ and $54=168A+24B\implies$

$24A=6\implies A=\dfrac14$.  Can you solve now for $B, C, $ and $D$?