# Prove combinatorically $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 = n{n+1 \choose 2} - {n+1 \choose 3 } $

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

**Problem**: Prove combinatorically that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 =  n{n+1 \choose 2} - {n+1 \choose 3 }   $.

**My thoughts:** I rewrote the equation to be proved as $ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2 =  {n \choose 1 }{n+1 \choose 2} - { n \choose 0 }{n+1 \choose 3 }   $
Then I was thinking to myself that $ k^2 $ on the left side could represent the number of length-2 strings over alphabet of size $ k$.
And the right hand side could be interpreted as: Let $ A $ represent the set of $ 2n+1 $ people composed of two sets: $ B $ the set of $ n+1  $ boys and $ C $ the set of $ n $ girls. $ {n \choose 1 }{n+1 \choose 2} $ could be thought as the set of all possible ways to create a commission made from $ 2 $ boys and $ 1 $ girl ( and similarly for $ { n \choose 0 }{n+1 \choose 3 }  $ ).

However, thinking of $ A $ as made from sets $ B ,C $  of boys and girls doesn't seem to make sense of the **difference** in the right side between the binomials. Also, thinking of the left hand side as a way of choosing number of length-2 strings over alphabet of size $ k$ doesn't make me see how the left-side correlates to the right-hand side.  Can you please help me on how to prove the equation?

Comment: This problem has been discussed at some length here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95047/combinatorial-interpretation-of-sum-of-squares-cubes

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it. I went over some posts before posting but didn't notice this. I still have to prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \binom{n+1}{2} + 2 \binom{n+1}{3} =  n{n+1 \choose 2} - {n+1 \choose 3 }  $

Comment: Ok, I understand  when the problem is phrased as $ \binom{n+1}{2} + 2 \binom{n+1}{3}  $. But I have difficulty for the form $ n{n+1 \choose 2} - {n+1 \choose 3 } $. I thought about it, we are creating a triple $ (i,j,k) $. For $ n{n+1 \choose 2} $, $ {n+1 \choose 2} $  means we choose $ 2 $ elements from the set $ \{0,...,n \} $ and $ n $ means we chose an element from the set $\{1,...,n \}$ , we'll have 3 elements in total, we don't care about two elements but we take some third element in these choices to be the largest or equal from those two. But why do I have " $- {n+1 \choose 3 }$ " ?

Comment: The triple $ (i,j,k) $ is such that $   0 \leq i \leq  j \leq k-1$ and $  1\leq k \leq n $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boy is numbered from $1$ to $n$, the girls from $1$ to $n+1$.   We count the number of triples $(leftgirl,boy,rightgirl)$ with $boy$ less than both $girl$s.  For example $(2,1,3)$ or $(6,5,6)$.
The boy has a girl's photo in each hand, possibly the same one, and the girls both have a higher number than the boy.  Boy $1$ has $n$ choices for each photo, but boy $n$ only has one choice for each photo.  That is the sum of $k^2$.
The boy and the left-hand girl can be any pair of numbers, with the girl the higher number.  That is $n+1\choose 2$.
The right-hand girl can be any number not equal to the boy.  That is $n$.
But now remove those with the right-hand girl less than the boy.  That is $n+1\choose3$.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what is the set you are counting - is it the set of pairs of boys and girls ranked? ( like $ \langle boy_1, girl_2 \rangle $ where $boy_1$<$ girl_2 $ ) can you please give me an example of an element of the set?