# How to prove that $(1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3)=(1+2+\cdots+n)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series, induction, proof-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intuitive explanation for the identity $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/intuitive-explanation-for-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-l)

> How can one prove that $$(1^3+2^3+3^3+\cdots+n^3)=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)^2$$

Let $T_1=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Now, $T_2=(1^2+2^2+3^2+\cdots+n^2)$.

$T_2=((1^2+n^2)+(2^2+(n-1)^2)+(3^2+(n-2)^2)+\cdots+(\frac{n+1}{2})^2)$, when $n$ is odd

$T_2=((1^2+n^2)+(2^2+(n-1)^2)+(3^2+(n-2)^2)+\cdots+(k^2+(n-k+1)^2))$, when $n$ is even, where, $k=\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: @Sidd: I know this one by heart because I was the first to ask it a year and a half ago.  It has been asked many times, and at some point there were 3 or 4 existing duplicates.  I merged all of them into the single most upvoted question.  (Closing my original in the process) I will merge this one in as well in a few days to preserve Jennifer Dylan's answer.

Comment: @EricNaslund  I respectfully disagree with your duplicate suggestion. I think [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct?lq=1) is the actual duplicate, since it contains an actual inductive proof (e.g. alok's answer) rather than intuitive *explanations*.