# Mathematical Induction and telescoping series

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Use a suitable telescoping sum to find a simpler expression for the sum $1^4+2^4+...+n^4$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Prove by mathematical induction

Comment: Chances are you have seen something similar done for $1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$, or maybe for $1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2$, and you could try to do similar steps for this one.

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/321000/12042) applies the technique to the sum of cubes; try using it as a model.

Answer (score 2):

The suitable telescoping sum might be
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left[(k+1)^5-k^5\right]=(n+1)^5-1.$$
By expanding the left hand side and recalling formulas for $\sum k$, $\sum k^2$ and $\sum k^3$, you can solve for the desired sum.