# The identity of a polynomial sum

Tags: exponential-sum

I am wondering if there is a recursive formula to calculate
$$S=1^{k}+2^{k}+3^{k}+\dots+n^{k}$$
Where $k$ and $n$ are natural numbers.

Comment: $f(x) = f(x-1)+x^k?$

Comment: I intended to find something depending on k in the recurrence,not the n....

Comment: I was looking for this clarification indeed. That's why didn't add it as answer :)

Comment: Googling Faulhaber's formula should get you something decent.

Comment: Check [this paper](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/Beardon201-213.pdf).

Comment: You can generalize this [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320985/how-to-determine-equation-for-sum-k-1n-k3/321000#321000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do,

$$f[k][n]=f[k][n-1]+(f[k-1][n]-f[k-1][n-1])\cdot n$$

where $f[k][n] = 1^k+2^k+\dots+n^k$. so we get $n^{k-1} = (f[k-1][n]-f[k-1][n-1])$ and multiplying both side with $n$ we get $n^k=(f[k-1][n]-f[k-1][n-1])\cdot n$.

And $f[k][n-1]+n^k = f[k][n]$