# How to find $\sum n^3$ if $\sum n^2$ is given

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

Problem :

Find $\sum_{j=1}^n j^3$ if $\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 =2870$

Can we use the following method :

$\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ = 2870..

( As sum of the square of first n natural number is $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$)

But how do we proceed from here to get the result?

Comment: You could factor 2870. Then identify the factors with those in $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ to find $n$.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sum n^3$ ?

Comment: yeah it is $[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}]^2$ @ Thomas

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320985/how-to-determine-equation-for-sum-k-1n-k3/321000#321000).

Comment: I've added ([tag:summation]) tag, which is intended specifically [for finite sums](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/summation/info) (among other things).

Answer (score 6):

Note that $n(n+1)(2n+1)=2n(n+1)(n+1/2)$. Letting $m=n+1/2$, we get:

$$2780\cdot 3 = (m-1/2)(m+1/2)m = m^3-m/4$$ So we want $m$ to be just over $\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 2780}$. That should give you a candidate for $n$. You should check that this $n$ works.

Note: The $m$ trick is a bit of magic, but we know that $n(n+1)(2n+1)$ grows "like" $2n^3$, so even if you don't find the $m$ trick, you can guess it will be near $\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 2780}$. The $m$ trick makes it clear that if such $n$ exists, there has to be only a single value.

Answer (score 3):

First we factor $2870$: 
$$2870=(20\times 21\times 41)/6$$
We have
$$(k+1)^4-k^4= 4k^3+6k^2+4k+1$$
so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n=20}(k+1)^4-k^4=(21)^4-1=4\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n=20} k^3}_{=S}+6\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n=20}k^2}_{=2870}+4\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n=20}k}_{=20\times21/2}+\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{n=20}1}_{=20}$$
and then we find $S$.

Comment: One more "for the road"!

Answer (score 2):

One more way: 1) use perturbation method (see Concrete Mathematicxs of and 2) solve the equation you have for $n$.

The equation $2n^3+2n^2+n-6 \cdot 2870=0$ has only 1 real root: $n=20$.
Now use perturbation method, denote $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^4$
 and $S^{\ast}_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$
$$
S_n +(n+1)^4=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k+1)^4+1=S_n+4 \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3+6 \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2+4\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+n+1
$$
Here $S_n$ cancel out, you have thee value for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$, from which you can also find the value for $\sum_{k=1}^nk$ (it is 210), so you can easily find the value for $S^{\ast}_n$.

Comment: Why to use perturbation method if $n$ is known?