# Working out Riemann sums

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$ on an interval $[-a, a]$.

Then my Riemann sum becomes:

$$\displaystyle S = \sum^{n-1}_{k = 0}a_{k}[x_{k} - x_{k - 1}]$$

where $a_{k}$ is the internal point of the subinterval $[x_{k-1}, x_{k}]$ of the partition $P = \{ x_{0}, x_{1}, ..., x_{n} \}$. How do I progress with this?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645932/prove-int-limits-0b-x3-fracb44-by-considering-partitions-0-b).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do a Riemann Integral of a **rational** function...

Comment: @DonAntonio, what about the real function $f(x) = x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$, I was able to do the latter so just wrote up the first.

Comment: That is fine, @user2850514 : the example you give is a function defined for **all** real numbers. Your question's data is a function from the rationals to the rationals...very different.

Comment: @DonAntonio So how do I go about that?

Comment: @user2850514 I've no idea. Why is that function of yours defined *only* on the rationals? And if it for whatever reason, why would you want to do Riemann Summs with it?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well the function as a whole is $f(x) = x$ for rational $x$ and $f(x) = 0$ for irrational $x$, I want to show that the Riemann integral of an arbitrary interval $[-\delta, \delta]$ does not exist, to do so I am working them out separately and showing a contradiction.

Comment: Oooh, **now** I see ! Why didn't you write so in the question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **any** subinterval of **any** partition of the interval $\;[-\delta,\delta]\;$, we can always choose *one* $\;0<a_l\in\Bbb Q\;$ and all the rest of the $\;a_k\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$ , so in this case we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k(x_k-x_{k-1})=a_l(x_l-x_{l-1})>0$$

On the other hand, if **all** the $\;a_i\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\;$ , then the sum is obviously zero. This proves the Riemann sums do not approach any definite limit and thus the function isn't integrable.

Comment: Why can we simply ignore the $a_{k}$ within the summation?

Comment: Because I thought it was $\;f(x)=1\;$ for $\;x\in\Bbb Q\;$, @user2850514. But it's possible to mend this. I shall do this later as I've no time now.

Comment: Have you been able to fix this?

Comment: @user2850514, I have now. Check it.