# Geometrical interpretation of $(\sum_{k=1}^n k)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$

Tags: summation, induction

Using induction it is straight forward to show
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3.$$
But is there also a geometrical interpretation that "proves" this fact? By just looking at those formulas I don't see why they should be equal.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/320985/9754

Answer (score 25):

The clearest proof I've seen is this one, which comes from [here](http://hyrodium.tumblr.com/post/94237657514/inspired-by-this-twocubes-post-and-asked-to-make): you just have to stare at it for a few seconds to see how it works. (It's a variant of the other proofs, of course, but actually has cubes in it.)

[image: Animation]

Answer (score 7):

[image]

There is this picture. Here, they represent $x^3$ as $x$ squares of side length $x$. The big square is the sum of all numbers up to $x$.

Comment: Who are they?  Add a reference.

Answer (score 3):

page 86 ,85
book :proof without words
author : roger nelsen
you can find here many kind of this proof
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This identity is sometimes called **Nicomachus's theorem.** If you type this in google, you'll recieve numerous pictures.

**1.**
[image]

**2.**[image]

**3.**[image]

Answer (score 1):

An engineering style fourier-approach. You may not consider this to be very intuitively "geometric", but I thought it could be interesting however.

Consider the time-signal $[1,2,...,k]$ (A linear function or "triangle wave"). The LHS is the square of the DC component of the signal in the temporal/spatial domain which is straight forward to calculate. The RHS is the iterated convolution of the fourier transform of [1,2,3,...,k] three times and then DC component of that.

Comment: Could you please take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440181/translation-of-a-certain-proof-of-sum-k2-sum-k3)