# Translation of a certain proof of $(\sum k)^2 = \sum k^3 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fourier-series

In the question: [Geometrical interpretation of $(\sum_{k=1}^n k)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305097/geometrical-interpretation-of-sum-k-1n-k2-sum-k-1n-k3) the mysterious last answer involves concepts from electrical engineering and signal processing:

> Consider the time-signal [1,2,...,k] (A linear function or "triangle wave"). The LHS is the square of the DC component of the signal in the temporal/spatial domain which is straight forward to calculate. The RHS is the iterated convolution of the fourier transform of [1,2,3,...,k] three times and then DC component of that.

Can anyone supply details here?  What does he mean **[triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave)** and **[DC component](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/12972/discrete-fourier-transform-what-is-the-dc-term-really)**?  Sounds like tuning a radio then proving a theorem, but that is what makes math great.

Comment: I'd rather guess "DC component" is the time average, the direct current component of a voltage signal. To be precise it should be $\frac 1 n \sum_{k=1}^n k$, but the factor $\frac 1 n$ probably doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 5):

Yes Christoph is on the right idea and there is some technical details involved here. Some FFTs normalize the sum to be $1/n$ and some don't and some normalize in a third way and so on, so I need to check which of these my local FFT actually does to be able to check myself. Anyway first of all we need a function to work with, and we choose the linear function below, basically $f(x) = x$ :

[image]

The theory behind this all is based on applying the convolution theorem of Fourier transforms:

$$\mathcal{F}(f^3) = \mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(f)$$
together with the fact that for the frequency 0, the exponential factor becomes 1 and the  fourier transform is a sum (or in the continous case an integral):
$$\mathcal{F}(g)[0] = \sum_{k=1}^N g(k)$$
possibly times a factor, depending on normalization. This is what the left hand side amounts to. The right hand side is with the same reasoning $(\mathcal{F}(f)[0])^2$. Note the square is last so it is on the result of the sum.

Comment: You basically restated that $(\mathcal F(f)[0])^2=(\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(f)*\mathcal{F}(f))[0]$ for $f(j)=j$. How is it shown without grunt work given that you need two convolutions?

Comment: OK it's reasonable that $\mathcal{F}(f^3)[0] =  \sum f(k)^3$ but can you prove the other side? $$ \big[ \mathcal{F}(f)\ast \mathcal{F}(f)\ast\mathcal{F}(f)\big][0] = \big[\sum f(k)\big]^2$$

Comment: I think I had it in my head at some point, but sadly it seems to have run and hid.

Comment: @mathreadler this is a key point -- I cannot award the bounty without it.   we know this formula is more general since the divisor function also does it $ \sum \tau(k)^3  = \big(\sum \tau(k)\big)^2$ Possibly this is not true for all $f$ - then just some short explanation of when this works.

Comment: Yes I agree you should not award the bounty unless I figure out an explanation why it is true for this particular $f$.