# Intuitively, why is $\sum_{r=0}^n r^3 =\bigg(\sum_{r=0}^n r \bigg)^2$?

Tags: summation

---

A duplicate question probably exists, but I couldn't find one. Please let me know if one is found and I'll delete this.

---

We know that:

$$\sum_{r=0}^n r=\frac12n(n+1)$$
and that:
$$\sum_{r=0}^n r^3 =\frac14 n^2(n+1)^2$$
and these are easily proven by induction:
$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)=\frac{n^2+n+2n+2}{2}=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}=\frac12(n+1)(n+2)$$
and:
$$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+(n+1)^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2+4(n+1)^3}{4}$$
$$= \frac{(n+1)^2(n^2+4n+4)}{4}=\frac 14(n+1)^2(n+2)^2$$

We can see that, from the results obtained, $$\sum_{r=0}^n r^3 =\bigg(\sum_{r=0}^n r\bigg)^2$$

What I am curious to know is, is there a reason why this is the case, other than the numbers just showing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a pretty proof without words in an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2437635/show-that-displaystyle-left-sum-r-1n-r-right2-sum-r-1n-r3-without?rq=1).  For my two cents, I think this is one of those remarkable facts, like the Pythagorean theorem, that has many proofs but no one "reason".