# How do you "simplify" the sigma sign when it is raised to a power?

Tags: summation

How do you simplify the following expression:

$$\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}k \right)^2$$

I am supposed to show that

$$\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}k \right)^2 = \sum^{n}_{k=1}k^{3} $$

The problem is I do not really know how to *manipulate* the sigma sign. I know that I (probably) need to use induction somehow, but the main question is how do you "simplify" the sigma sign when it is raised to a power. Due to the problem itself I know that (most likely); $$\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}k \right)^2 = \sum^{n}_{k=1}k^{3} $$ so is it possible to simply manipulate the LHS so that it looks like the RHS?

Comment: $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)^2=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)\cdot \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)$.  Now, what do you know about $\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)$?  Do you know a nice convenient expression for it?  If you don't, can you come up with a conjecture after looking at the pattern and prove it via induction?  Pictures might help for a geometric interpretation for this step.  Now, can you continue via induction for the overall claim?

Comment: You need to get a single expression for the sum represented by the sigma sign.....which in this case is equal to $n(n+1)/2$. Then you can square this result to obtain the final answer.

Comment: @SirJMP Thank you. So I need to show the following with induction $\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^{3} = \frac{1}{4}(n^{2} + n)^{2}$

Comment: Yes. You can also prove it by generating the required series....which Shaswata has done beautifully in his answer....and then complete using induction.

Comment: In general, remember that sigma notation is just shorthand for a sum $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k = (a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n)$, and that the usual distributive laws apply: $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)^2
= \left( \sum_{j=1}^n j \right) \cdot \left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)
= \sum_{j=1}^n \left( j \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)
= \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n jk$. In this particular case, that won't help you much (it's much easier to apply the closed-form expression for $\sum_{k=1}^n k$), but it's a useful technique in general: if you can handle plain old sums, you can handle (finite) sigma expressions.

Comment: See also the following posts: [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct) and [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/62171). [Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i) and [other posts linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/61482).

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320985/how-to-determine-equation-for-sum-k-1n-k3) may be of help on the right side of the equation. And, as linked in that question, a [handy table](http://www.math.com/tables/expansion/power.htm) of other sums of powers.

Answer (score 15):

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\right)^2-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k+\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\right)$$

$$=(n+1)\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}+\frac{(n+1)(n)}{2}\right)=(n+1)^3$$

I guess you can do the rest now since you have already figured out that you need to use induction.

Answer (score 6):

This identity is a coincidence — it is not proven by doing general series manipulations, but instead by simply computing the left and right hand sides and confirming they're equal.

Comment: Beware of calling things coincidences. I've seen a geometric explanation of why this holds before, though I cannot recall it right now.

Comment: Actually Martin Sleziak provides links to such geometric explanations in his comment on the OP.

Comment: It appears that the point (a very pertinent one (+1)) by made in this solution is that, in general, the square of a summation cannot be manipulated into a single neat summation, and that the identity in the question is probably a special case.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
\sum^{n}_{k=1}k&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
\left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}k\right)^2&=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2\\
\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2&=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^3&=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\\
\therefore \left(\sum^{n}_{k=1}k\right)^2&=\sum^{n}_{k=1}k^3
\end{align} $$