# Prove by induction that $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + .....+ n^3= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ for all $n\geq1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that $1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + .....+ n^3= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ for all $n\geq1$.

Can anyone explain? Because I have no clue where to begin. I mean, I can show that $1^3+ 2^3 +...+ (k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$, but then I don't know where to go. I need further explanation to prove it.

thank you so much for help

Sincerely

Comment: relevant: http://www.basic-mathematics.com/proof-by-mathematical-induction.html

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-limits-k-1n-k3-left-sum-limits-k-1n-k-ri

Comment: Yauzaah! Only after reviewing the editing I realized that weird "idk" actually means "I don't know"...My heart bleeds for the last generation's grammar skills...and laziness.

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

$$1^3=\frac{1^2\cdot2^2}4\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

$$1^3+2^3+\ldots+n^3+(n+1)^3\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}4+(n+1)^3=$$

$$=\frac{(n+1)^2}4\left(n^2+4(n+1)\right)=\ldots\ldots\;\;\;\color{green}\checkmark$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's the general idea behind the Principle of Mathematical Induction, a la a staircase metaphor:

> (1) Show that the bottom step of the staircase is painted.
>
> (2) Show that, if a given step of the staircase is painted, then the next step up is painted, too.

PMI lets us conclude that *all* of the steps are painted. Is this a visually convincing metaphor?

In light of your example, it seems you've completed step 2. All that's left is to complete step 1--that is, show that $$1^3=\frac{1^2\cdot 2^2}4.$$