# Prove $1^3+2^3+...+n^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, proof-verification, induction

My approach is to solve this by induction.

**Base case:** $n=1$

$1^3 = 1^2 = 1$

**Inductive Step:** Suppose that  $1^3+2^3+...+n^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2$  holds for all positive integers $n$. We use that to show that  $1^3+2^3+...+n^3 + (n+1)^3 = (1+2+...+n+(n+1))^2$

$1^3+2^3+...+n^3 + (n+1)^3 = (1+2+...+n)^2 + (n+1)^3$

And here is where I can no longer proceed. I know there must be some trick/computation that I am not seeing that will make this proof easier. Help? Thanks!!

Comment: See also: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089990/can-you-formalize-the-proof-that-1-2-cdots-n2-13-23-cdots-n/), and about 50 other of more or less the same question.

Comment: You should write, in the inductive step: Suppose … holds for *some* positive integer $n$. If it holds for all, there's nothing to prove.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i + (n+1)\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i\right)^2 + 2(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i + (n+1)^2
$$
The second and third terms are
$$
2(n+1)\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n+1)^2 = (n+1)^2(n+1) = (n+1)^3
$$
Thus 
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\right)^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n i \right)^2 +(n+1)^3
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact

$$(1+2+3+\ldots+n)=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$
Then you just have to prove that
$$\frac{n^2(n-1)^2}{4}+(n+1)^3=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: \begin{align*}
(1+2+\dots+n+(n+1))^2&=(1+2+\dots+n)^2+2(1+2+\dots+n)(n+1)+(n+1)^2 \\
&=1^3+\dots+n^3+2(1+2+\dots+n)(n+1)+(n+1)^2\\
&=1^3+\dots+n^3+n(n+1)^2+(n+1)^2\\
&=1^3+\dots+n^3+(n+1)^3\end{align*}