# Proofs of theorems, where picture is sufficient

Tags: intuition, alternative-proof

A while ago I have had the pleasure to come across those [lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXHHvoaSctc) of **Topology & Geometry** by Dr Tadashi Tokieda (I do recommend watching at least the first lecture, both parts). My question is based primarily on the [second part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wj5foqm5MfM). In few words my question is about **Proofs done by picture**.

During my studies, I must say, that I was not (*am not*) very motivated to draw/sketch the problems we faced (face). I think this is related to the fact, that coming from high school students are not used to rigorous proofs/arguments and tend to *prove something by giving, although general, but not sufficient example by picture*. I remember this happening during the class of geometry, e.g. discussing something only for *equilateral* triangle and not *arbitrary* triangle.

I think this process was motivated by our need to imagine the problem in a way we can understand it better. And I am still behind this idea, although I get the feeling, that mathematicians sometimes discourage this more than it is necessary (*drawing* etc.), because it does not represent the problem in general, or it is not really equivalent - discussing the problem and the picture. Also mathematical papers, books lack the presence of images (again, maybe this is only *my feeling* - and I also does not consider myself any great reader of math stuff) or have only few. It seems to me, that the pictures may not be there because of the extra work you need to put into it, while providing only non-equivalent intuition.

**Example (not really a picture-one)**

A few weeks ago we discussed the homotopy between two continous functions $f, g: [0,1] \to X$ such that $f(0) = g(0),\,f(1) = g(1)$ that is they form a loop (see - only intuition, there might be no loop - in case $f \equiv g$ or sth completely different). But I want to show different thing. Lets put $f\neq g$ and form a hole in the interior formed by $f,g$, e.g. $f,g$ create a loop around the origin in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we take the origin away, being left with $\mathbb{R}^2 \ \{(0,0)\}$. The problem is, that there is no way to find a homotopy from $f$ to $g$ because of the hole.

I've got the idea of a bit real life example being somewhat this case. Imagine a jacket with zipper. Let $f$ and $g$ be each *side* of the zipper. The only adjustment we need to make is close the zipper on both ends (normally you would start from one end, and the other is still open). Then ask your friend to stick a stick between the zipper and try to fasten it. No matter how you try, the stick prevents you from being able to do it (fun observation the *nothing = hole* is suddenly very *solid object* and the *space* is *nothing*).

This is not really one of the examples I would like you to show, but nothing better came to my mind right now (maybe aside from Pythagorean theorem).

**Question**

If you are still reading, yet have no idea, what is my question, here it is:

*Can you give an example of a theorem (maybe provide some additional background if you think it is necessary) from any branch of Mathematics (not only geometry) where a good picture is a sufficient proof (not that the picture would be the only thing used in the proof) of the theorem? Or that the truthness of the theorem is almost obvious from the theorem?*

I am aware that the fact, that mathematicians created the tools, which allow us to prove something without relying on an unreliable pictures is great step. I just get the feeling whether we haven't sometimes stepped a bit further than it is necessary.

**Mods**
I understand this, aside from others, can be opinion based, and I am prepared that this might be flagged and closed as off-topic, still I want to give it a try.

Comment: Are you looking for something that can be proven with a picture and absolutely no text at all?  Or can it be a picture with a few words to accompany it?  If the latter, there's a beautiful visual proof of the Pythagorean theorem that would make a good example.

Comment: No, I am not trying to be pedantic and looking for something extraordinary. I hoped, that the wall of text I created made it clear, that I am trying to receive some examples, where one can show a lot using a good picture, instead of giving _word-like_ proof, which might be hard to understand.

Comment: If you are looking for examples, then this has already been asked here *and* on MO. The one on MO is http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That is almost exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Unfortunately I was searching "Proofs by picture" not "Proofs without words". Should have asked 6 years ago, now this seems pretty much a duplicate. I'll go through those examples.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Well, I think the best would be to close/delete this question? Or link to the other, since this topic is much more long-term question than others, so maybe fresh attention to the original question will be appreciated?

Answer (score 4):

A picture is *never* sufficient.

A proof is an explanation of why something is true. A picture might be good enough to *suggest* such an explanation to the beholder but it is certainly not an explanation: the picture is not the proof.

Comment: Maybe the wall of text did not do the job. I understand the concept of proof (not in formal logic) being a way how to persuade somebody about truthness of some fact, using arguments, which the other side understand. What is the difference between a _word_ and a _picture_? It is a medium how to present sth. I think you could also argue about _word-like_ proof being insufficient (although this is much less frequent).

Answer (score 1):

You will find some high voted summation formulas on this site, which have been proofed graphical, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i).

Another one that comes to mind is a proof of Pythagoras theorem ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Pythagorean_proof)).