# Converting $(1+...+n)^2*(n+1)^3$ to $(2+...+2n)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I'm currently going through Calculus by Spivak by myself, and came across a proof by induction requiring to prove $1^3+...+n^3 = (1+...+n)^2$

Naturally, to prove this, I need to somehow convert $(1+...+n)^2+(n+1)^3$ to $(2+...+2n)^2$.
After quite a bit of thinking, I'm still not sure how to do this. I think i may be forgetting about some property of squares that we're supposed to be using.

Note: Please only provide a hint, not the complete answer. 
Edit: I was mistakenly taking $(1+...+n)^2*(n+1)^3$ rather than $(1+...+n)^2+(n+1)^3$. Corrected.

Comment: It seems that you are working on the proof which is also done in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct). The questions which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/62171) might be interesting for you, too. There are also proofs without induction; see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i) or [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squared_triangular_number#Proofs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Previous Answer**

Hint:
$$1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Can you take it from here?

**Revised Answer**

My apologies for not bothering to check more closely earlier, but I think your original equation
$$\left(1 + 2 + \ldots + n\right)^2\left(n + 1\right)^3 = \left(2 + 4 + \ldots + 2n\right)^2$$
is *not* an identity.

To see why, via a quick inspection, the highest power of $n$ on the LHS is $n^7$, while the highest power of $n$ on the RHS is $n^4$, a contradiction.

Therefore, your proposed equation is not an identity.

Comment: I'm already familiar with that identity, but i'm afraid not. After converting the notation inside and multiplying it by (n+1)^3, where do i go? I.e, how do i convert it into the statement required?

Comment: The left side is actually a polynomial with degree $7$ not $5$ and the right side is a polynomial of degree $4$ not $2$. Each side as a summation with a number of terms that depends on $n$.

Comment: I made a mistake where i, instead of adding $(n+1)^3$, was multiplying it. Also, i did not imply that $(1+2+...+n)^2(n+1)^2 = (2+4+...+2n)^2$ but rather $(1+2+...+n)^2(n+1)^2 = (2+2+3+4+...+2n)^2$. I tried to simplify it by integrating the n + 1 into the existing equation, something that i now realize was a very stupid mistake. Your original hint was enough to get me to the right answer after i realized my mistake.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy!  I've made the appropriate edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Naturally, to prove this, i need to somehow convert $(1+...+n)^2*(n+1)^3$ to $(2+...+2n)^2$.

Unfortunately, "$(1+...+n)^2*(n+1)^3 = (2+...+2n)^2$" is not true for all $n$. Once you simplify the summations, the left side will be a polynomial with degree $2 \cdot 2 + 3 = 7$ while the right side will be a polynomial with degree $2 \cdot 2 = 4$.

The induction step is to assume that $$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3 = (1+2+\cdots+n)^2$$
 for some integer $n$, and then prove that $$1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3+(n+1)^3 = (1+2+\cdots+n+(n+1))^2.$$

As Arnie Dris suggested, the identity $1+2+\cdots+n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is useful.

Note that \begin{align*}& (1+2+\cdots+(n+1))^2 - (1+2+\cdots+n)^2 \\ &= \left[\dfrac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right]^2-\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2 \\ &=\dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}\left[(n+2)^2-n^2\right] \\ &= \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{4}[4n+4] \\ &= (n+1)^3\end{align*}

Do you see how to complete the proof using this?

Answer (score 0):

No i dont think so . (Of above equation,induction one) see RHS can be simplied to $\frac{(n)^2(n+1)^2}{4}$ and we all know that summation $\sum n^3=\frac{(n^2)(n+1)^2}{4}$  and what you are proving doesnt seem to be true the second equation put $n=2$ and you get $243=36$ please see what you have interpreted wrongly in the proof

Comment: The second equation is for the step two of induction, i.e where you prove that if k is true, k+1 is true. The second equation is asking how to convert $1^3 + ... + n^3 + (n+1)^3 = (1+...+n)^2*(n+1)^3$ to the same statement as what you get when you substitute n as n + 1.

Comment: Update: My mistake. I was multiply by $(n+1)^3$ rather than adding it.

Comment: Okay please include it in body as i misinterpreted it