# Intuitive reason for why $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i\right)^2 = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n i^3$

Tags: summation

Is there any intuitive reason or deeper meaning to why the following equality holds?

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^n i\right)^2 =  \sum_{i=0}^n i^3$$

I'm not looking for a proof of this, I'm looking for some explanation for this equality if it isn't just a coincidence.

Comment: For more intuitive answers, look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i

Comment: There is no intuition for this. Indeed the image posted by @RobertZ is not intuitive at all.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Take a look at [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Nicomachus_theorem_3D.svg) (a nice visual proof):

[image]

Is that convincing?

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. Things like this are what I like the most about maths. Thanks

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury You Can find more like this in "Proof Without Words" Books...

Comment: nice answer @robert

Answer (score 1):

From the easy identity $(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2=4n$, we deduce

$$n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2-n^2(n-1)^2}4=S_n-S_{n-1}.$$

By telescoping, the sum of consecutive cubes is always a difference of squares.

In particular, the sum of the first cubes is always a *perfect square*.

---

Then, it should be intuitive that the sum of the $p^{th}$ powers of the integers are polynomials of degree $p+1$, and comparing to integrals, the leading term must be

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^p\sim\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}.$$

So, looking for a case such that $$\left(\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}\right)^2=\frac{n^{q+1}}{q+1}$$

we find the only solution

$$\left(\frac{n^2}2\right)^2=\frac{n^4}4$$ giving identical asymptotic behaviours.

---

Combining the previous two properties, the two sequences must coincide exactly.

Comment: dear prof. Yves Daoust can you help me for ask Math question in stack.exchange??..Because this is so hard question for ask..And I can not turn the question into mathematics language..(+latex and englosh language)..Please..can you help me as your Little student.. :( I prepared direk link.. Can you look??

Comment: @MathLife: enter your question as usual and I'll take a look. But I am not doing the LaTeX encoding for you. You need to learn.