# For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ do we have $\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k^3 = (\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k)^2$?

Tags: summation

I have a question that I don't know how to solve.

> For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ do we have $$\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k^3 = (\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k)^2\quad ?$$.

Here's what I've tried:

\begin{align*}\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k^3 = (\sum\limits^n_{k=0} k)^2 & \Leftrightarrow 1+8+27+\cdots+n^3 = (1+2+3+\cdots+n)^2\\ & \Leftrightarrow \sqrt{1+8+27+\cdots+n^3} = 1+2+3+\cdots+n \end{align*}

Comment: You can use induction and $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$ for $n\in \mathbf N$.

Comment: Have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882161/intuitive-reason-for-why-left-displaystyle-sum-i-0n-i-right2-displays/

Comment: Have a look at Bernoulli's three theorems for expansion of sums, if you are interested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It holds for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Is this sufficiently convincing:[image]

Note. This formula has been known for 2000 years. It is due to [Nicomachus of Gerasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicomachus).

Answer (score 0):

There is a formula for the LHS (sum of consecutive cubes -- proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)) that says it's equal to $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$, which is therefore equal to the RHS for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$