# How would you intuitively explain why $\sum_{i = 1}^n i^3 = \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n i \right)^2$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I recently brushed up on the formulas

\begin{align}
\sum_{i = 1}^n i &= \frac{n(n+1)}{2},\\
\sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 &= \frac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6},\\
\sum_{i = 1}^n i^3 &= \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4},
\end{align}

and I could not believe I never noticed the identity $\sum_{i = 1}^n i^3 = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n i\right)^2$. Is there an obvious reason why this should be the case?

I purposefully kept the question open to interpretation because I would love to see how you reason about this fact that I should have noticed ages ago.

Comment: +1, good question. Obviously, it should be easy to *prove*, like via induction. But if the question is, "Is it obvious?" Then no, not to me...

Comment: @AdamRubinson I changed the question, thank you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1882161/96384, and many other duplicates.

Comment: Yes it does, I wasn't able to find those. Thank you. I'll keep the post up so it's easier to find for someone else if they ever have the same question.