# Summation of product of three terms in AP

Tags: summation

Here is an interesting relationship:

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+m)(r+2m)=\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m} r\right)\tag{1}$$
$$\text{i.e.} \;\; 1\cdot(1+m)(1+2m)+2\cdot (2+m)(2+2m)+3\cdot (3+m)(3+2m)+\cdots +n(n+m)(n+2m)=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)(1+2+3+\cdots+(n+2m))$$
which gives the following for the first few values of $m$:
$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
&1\cdot 1\cdot 1+2\cdot 2\cdot2+3\cdot3\cdot3+\cdots+n\cdot n\cdot n&&=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)(1+2+3+\cdots+n)\\
&1\cdot2\cdot3+2\cdot3\cdot4+3\cdot5\cdot7+\cdots+n(n+1)(n+2)&&=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)(1+2+3+\cdots+(n+2))\\
&1\cdot3\cdot5+2\cdot4\cdot6+3\cdot5\cdot7+\cdots+n(n+2)(n+4)&&=(1+2+3+\cdots+n)(1+2+3+\cdots+(n+4))\\ \end{align}$$

This can be proven by expanding both sides and finding that the result is 
$$\frac {n(n+1)}2\cdot \frac {(n+2m)(n+2m+1)}2\tag{2}$$

> **Question**
>   Can  the result can be proven without expansion to the closed form but only by manipulating summands and limits, i.e. prove $(1)$ without first expanding to $(2)$?

---

Some interesting but commonly-known results follow from this.

Setting $m=0$ gives the "sum of cubes as square of sum of integers" result:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)^2$$

Setting $m=1$ gives the "discrete integral"

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^\overline{3}=\frac{\;n^\overline{4}}4$$
where $r^\overline{a}$ is the symbol for the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but FWIW the two sides are quadratics in $m$ which you showed match at $2$ points. If you verify the equality at a $3^{rd}$ point e.g. $m=-1$ then that would prove the identity in general.

Comment: Some quick things I can see, $\sum r \mid \sum r (r+m) (r + 2m) \dots (r+km)$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, my guess is that it continues in this fashion forever. This might be worth proving?

Comment: Other wild guesses, if $k$ above is even, like in your case, then the factor follows a similar form to yours above. For $k=4$, it is $\sum_1^n r \sum_1^{4m + n} r \frac{9m^2 + 8mn + 4m + 2n^2 + 2n - 1}{3}$. Similar but more ugly fraction for $k=6$. The fraction is $240m^4 + 312m^3n + 156m^3 + 160m^2n^2 + 160m^2n - 26m^2 + 36mn^3 + 54mn^2 - 6mn + 3n^4 + 6n^3 - n^2 - 4n + 2$ all over $6$.

Comment: btw, i'm using mathematica to play about with this, `Sum[ Product[r + k*m, {k, 0, 3}], {r, 1, n}]` change the 3 for the closed form for various other ones. I suppose i'm not doing anything helpful, since i'm not actually answering the question. I feel the answer is just fancy combinatorics.

Answer (score 4):

I will use the identity

$$\sum_{r=1}^n r^3=\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)^2$$

It can be proved without direct expansion. (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1215805/268334)

\begin{align}
&\;\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+m)(r+2m)\\
=&\;\sum_{r=1}^n [(r+m)^3-m^2(r+m)]\\
=&\;\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r^3-\sum_{r=1}^mr^3-m^2\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r\right)^2-\left(\sum_{r=1}^mr\right)^2-m^2\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r-\sum_{r=1}^mr\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r+\sum_{r=1}^mr\right)-m^2\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r+\sum_{r=1}^mr\right)-m^2\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n (r+m)\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+m}r+\sum_{r=1}^mr-m^2\right)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r+mn\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r-\sum_{r=1}^m(r+m+n)+\sum_{r=1}^mr-m^2\right)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r+mn\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r-m(m+n)-m^2\right)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r+mn\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r-\sum_{r=1}^m(r+m+n)+\sum_{r=1}^mr-m^2\right)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r+mn\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r-m(2m+n)\right)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r\right)+mn\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r-m(2m+n)\sum_{r=1}^nr-m^2n(2m+n)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r\right)+\frac{1}{2}mn(n+2m)(n+2m+1)\\
&\qquad-\frac{1}{2}m(2m+n)n(n+1)-m^2n(2m+n)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r\right)+\frac{1}{2}mn(n+2m)(n+2m+1-n-1-2m)\\
=&\;\left(\sum_{r=1}^n r\right)\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your solution (+1).

Comment: @hypergeometric But I believe there must be a more beautiful way to prove it.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the summation
$$\sum_{i=1}^si \sum_{j=1}^{s+2m}j$$
When $s=r-1$, the summation is equal to 
$$\big(1+2+\cdots+(r-1)\big)\big(1+2+3+\cdots+(r-1+2m)\big)$$
When $s=r$, the summation is equal to 
$$\big(1+2+\cdots+(r-1)+r\big)\big(1+2+3+\cdots+(r-1+2m)+(r+2m)\big)$$
New terms arising from putting $s=r$ are:

$$\require{cancel}\begin{align}
&\quad r\sum_{i=1}^{r+2m}i&&+(r+2m)\sum_{j=1}^rj&&-r(r+2m)\\
&=r\sum_{i=0}^{r+2m}i&&+(r+2m)\sum_{j=0}^rj&&-r(r+2m)\tag{1}\\
&=r\sum_{i=0}^{r+2m}\big(r+2m-i\big)&&+(r+2m)\sum_{j=0}^r \big(r-j\big)&&-r(r+2m)\tag{2}\\
&=\frac 12 r\sum_{i=0}^{r+2m}(r+2m)&&+\frac 12 (r+2m)\sum_{j=0}^r r&&-r(r+2m)\tag{(1)+(2))/2}\\
&=\frac 12 r(r+2m)\sum_{i=0}^{r+2m}1&&+\frac 12 r(r+2m)\sum_{j=0}^r 1&&-r(r+2m)\\
&=\frac 12 r(r+2m)\sum_{i=1}^{r+2m}1&&+\frac 12 r(r+2m)\sum_{j=1}^r 1&&\cancel{-r(r+2m)}\\
&\; + \cancel{\frac 12 r(r+2m)}&&+\cancel{\frac 12 r(r+2m)}\\
&=r(r+2m)\frac {r+2m}2&&+r(r+2m)\frac r2\\
&=r(r+m)(r+2m)
\end{align}$$
Summing from $r=1$ to $n$ gives

$$\color{red}{\sum_{r=1}^n r\sum_{r=1}^{n+2m}r=\sum_{r=1}^n r(r+m)(r+2m)}$$