# Summation of series: How can we prove that $\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m}\right)^2=\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m^3}$ holds true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, induction

***Question:*** How can we prove that $$\displaystyle\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m}\right)^2=\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m^3}$$ holds true?

***Edit:-*** Actually I am new at Stack Exchange and Mathjx. I knew it's geometrical (graphical) representation. But I wanted to do it by induction. After all, (learning from comments) I have posted my own [complete solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2840352/573334) here.

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk\right)^2=\sum_{k=1}^nk^3$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes Please tell me how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: If you can compute the LHS, then you can prove both sides are equal by induction on $n$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That will be long method. Well I will try to do, but if there is any short method then please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: More elaboration on your attempt would be appreciated. [See also](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for more tips to inprove your question.

Comment: stare at the picture in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61483/59379), you will see the light.

Comment: @achillehui Waw!! It's really nice. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct)

Comment: Maybe you could mention in the question that you have posted your own solution as an answer - after all, the question was closed for missing context. (Although I am not sure whether it matter that much if the question is closed for this reason or closed as a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sum of AP;
$$\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m}\right)^2=(1+2+3+...+n)^{2}=\frac{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}$$

Now by Principle of Mathematical Induction,

for $n=1$,

$$\frac{1^{2}(2)^2}{4}=1$$ so its true for $n=1$,

now for $n=2$, $$\frac{2^{2}(3^{2})}{4}=9=1+2^{3}$$ so its true for $n=2$,

Now assume it holds for $n=k$, and now we can easily show that it is true for $n=k+1$ as follows;

Add $(k+1)^3$, which is $(k+1)^{\mathrm th}$ term of the LHS to both sides; then we get:
$$\begin{align*}
1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + k^3 + (k+1)^3 &= \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)^3\\
&= \frac{k^2(k+1)^2 + 4(k+1)^3}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2(k^2 + 4k + 4)}{4}\\
&= \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}.\\
1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + k^3 + (k+1)^3 &= \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}
\end{align*}$$
Hence the proof.

Comment: I'd say that the inductive step, which you skipped with *we can easily show*, is the most relevant part of the proof. And it is a bit unfortunate to say $n=k$, since you have already used the variable $k$ in a different meaning.

Comment: In any case, if you checked the linked question, you have probably seen that there are other posts on the site which give an inductive proof: [Proving $1^3+ 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = \left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ using induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62171).

Comment: I think now (after edit) it is correct.

Comment: Yet, the proof seems to be correct. (Almost the same as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62171/proving-13-23-cdots-n3-left-fracnn12-right2-using-induct/62198#62198).)

Comment: Actually I am new at stack exchange and Mathjx. I will improve slowly but surly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the common sum,
$$(1+2+3+...+n)^{2}=\frac{n^{2}(n+1)^{2}}{4}$$

Let us try induction, starting with $n=1$,

$$\frac{1^{2}(2)^2}{4}=1$$ so its true for $n=1$,

let us check for $n=2$, $$\frac{2^{2}(3^{2})}{4}=9=1+2^{3}$$ so its true for $n=2$,

Now assume it holds for $n$, can you show it holds for $n+1$.