# Prove that for a natural number $n$ is true $1^3 + 2^3 +...+ n^3 = (1 + 2 +...+ n)^2$

Tags: summation, induction

So I have to show that for all natural numbers $n$ is true

$$1^3 + 2^3 +...+ n^3 = (1 + 2 +...+ n)^2$$

For $n = 1$ I proved it and I came this far:

$$1^3 + 2^3 +...+ n^3 + (n + 1)^3 = (1 + 2 +...+ n)^2 + (n + 1)^3$$

I do not know how to prove that part. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61482)